# How does this "hello world!" program work?

Tags: c, obfuscation

```
int main(void)
{ 
    return('yes', *"no", **main, *********printf) ("hello world!\n") *0; 
}
```

outputs `hello world!`, but how does it actually work?

Comment: `return('yes', *"no", **main, *********printf) ("Its magical!\n") *0;`  By the way, i compiled it and it actually works ._.

Comment: you have a strange style to write software!You will never receive a job at me. :-)

Comment: C is really a perverted language :-)

Comment: As a pedantic remark, in ANSI C (in C89/90 as well) calling a variadic function (`printf` in this case) without declaring a prototype first is undefined behavior. So, from the pedantic point of view your program works only accidentally. You need to include `stdio.h` for it to become a defined C program.

Answer (score 46):

Two things really:

1. Function pointers don't dereference the same as other pointers.  `*main == main`
2. A comma separated list returns the value of the last element in the list

So if we simplify the pointers:

```
int main(void)
{ 
    return('yes', *"no", main, printf) ("hello world!\n") *0; 
}
```

And using the last element in the list as the value of the list

```
int main(void)
{ 
    return printf("hello world!\n") *0; 
}
```

`printf` returns the number of characters printed

```
int main(void)
{ 
    return 13 *0; 
}
```

And 13*0 is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Some friends of mine were having a mustache growing contest, and I had to shave.  So I wore a fake mustache that day.

Comment: to be pedantic: function pointers dereference just fine, but the resulting function designator will be immediately converted back to a function pointer

Comment: @rampion: I can't understand the last exercise example you've given. What do you mean by that? Please help me. Output is 0.

Comment: meet: what does that mean `main` returns?

Comment: @rampion: oh, main() always return 0. I understood. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

```
('yes', *"no", **main, *********printf)
```

will evaluate to `*********printf`, because comma operator evaluates its operands and returns value of last expression. `*********printf` is equal to printf, as dereferencing function pointer results in the same function pointer; it does nothing.

Next, result of first parenthesis, printf, is applied to ("hello world!\n") which results in text printed to screen. printf function returns number of characters written. That number is then multiplied with 0 and product is returned by main function.