# How to simulate Func<T1, T2, TResult> in C++?

Tags: c++

In C#, I use Func to replace Factories. For example:

```
class SqlDataFetcher    
{
    public Func<IConnection> CreateConnectionFunc;

    public void DoRead()
    {
        IConnection conn = CreateConnectionFunc(); // call the Func to retrieve a connection
    }
}

class Program    
{
    public void CreateConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(); 
    }

    public void Main()
    {
        SqlDataFetcher f = new SqlDataFetcher();
        f.CreateConnectionFunc = this.CreateConnection;
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I simulate the code above in C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use either `std::tr1::function<IConnection*()>` or `boost::function<IConnection*()>` as the equivalent of `Func<IConnection>`.

When you come to assign the function, you'll need to bind a object and a function together;

```
f.CreateConnectionFunc = this.CreateConnection;
```

would become

```
f.CreateConnectionFunc = std::tr1::bind(&Program::CreateConnection,this);
```

(That assumes `CreateConnection` is not a static function - your example code doesn't get its `statics` correct, so it's difficult to tell exactly what you meant).

Comment: +1, but `boost::function<IConnection *()>` (note the pointer).

Comment: Good point. And you might instead want to return a smart pointer to be explicit about ownership.

Comment: @avakar Isn't `IConnection*()` a function that returns a pointer to `IConnection`? Shouldn't it be `IConnection(*)()` instead?

Comment: @FredOverflow: `IConnection*()` is a function that returns a pointer to `IConnection`. `IConnection(*)()` is a pointer to a function that that returns an `IConnection` by value. `IConnection*()` is what's needed here, as returning an interface by value will lead to object slicing (or compile time errors).

Comment: @FredOverflow: 'IConnection*()' is fine - there really isn't a lot of difference between a function pointer and a function.

Comment: Well, the shorter function syntax is just syntactic sugar for the longer function pointer syntax, right? :)

Comment: Functions and function pointers are different, but functions implicitly convert into function pointers. The answers to this question go into the details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795575/how-does-dereferencing-of-a-function-pointer-happen