# Function pointers usage

Tags: c++, function-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does dereferencing of a function pointer happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795575/how-does-dereferencing-of-a-function-pointer-happen)

Hi All,
Why these two codes give the same output,
Case 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*mycall) (int a ,int b);
void addme(int a,int b);
void mulme(int a,int b);
void subme(int a,int b);

main()
{
    mycall x[10];
    x[0] = &addme;
    x[1] = &subme;
    x[2] = &mulme;
    (x[0])(5,2);
    (x[1])(5,2);
    (x[2])(5,2);
}

void addme(int a, int b) {
    printf("the value is %d\n",(a+b));
}
void mulme(int a, int b) {
    printf("the value is %d\n",(a*b));
}
void subme(int a, int b) {
    printf("the value is %d\n",(a-b));
}
```

Output:

```
the value is 7
the value is 3
the value is 10
```

Case 2 :

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*mycall) (int a ,int b);
void addme(int a,int b);
void mulme(int a,int b);
void subme(int a,int b);

main()
{
    mycall x[10];
    x[0] = &addme;
    x[1] = &subme;
    x[2] = &mulme;
    (*x[0])(5,2);
    (*x[1])(5,2);
    (*x[2])(5,2);
}

void addme(int a, int b) {
    printf("the value is %d\n",(a+b));
}
void mulme(int a, int b) {
    printf("the value is %d\n",(a*b));
}
void subme(int a, int b) {
    printf("the value is %d\n",(a-b));
}
```

Output:

```
the value is 7
the value is 3
the value is 10
```

Comment: Someone edit and put in code form please

Comment: Duplicate of [How does dereferencing of a function pointer happen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795575/how-does-dereferencing-of-a-function-pointer-happen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll simplify your question to show what I think you want to know.

Given

```
typedef void (*mycall)(int a, int b);
mycall f = somefunc;
```

you want to know why

```
(*f)(5, 2);
```

and

```
f(5.2);
```

do the same thing.  The answer is that a function name both represent a "function designator".  From the standard:

```
"A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the
operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, a function designator with
type ‘‘function returning type’’ is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to
function returning type’’."
```

When you use the indirection operator `*` on a  function pointer, that dereference is also a "function designator".  From the standard:

```
"The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is
a function designator;..."
```

So `f(5,2)` becomes essentially `(*f)(5,2)` by the first rule.  This becomes `call to function designated by f with parms (5,2)` by the second. The result is that `f(5,2)` and `(*f)(5,2)` do the same thing.

Comment: think you have a small typo, *mycall ---> myfunc

Comment: Nice answer and the great citation.

Answer (score 3):

Because function pointers are automatically resolved whether you use them with or without the dereference operator.

Answer (score 2):

you don't have to use & before function name

```
x[0] = addme;
x[1] = subme;
x[2] = mulme;
```

however both ways are valid.