# What does 'dereferencing' a pointer mean in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, dereference, c++-faq

Please include an example with the explanation.

Comment: this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795575/how-does-dereferencing-of-a-function-pointer-happen

Comment: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/

Comment: `int *p;` would define a pointer to an integer, and `*p` would dereference that pointer, meaning that it would actually retrieve the data that p points to.

Comment: Binky's Pointer Fun (http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/) is a GREAT video about pointers that might clarify things.  @Erik- You rock for putting up the Stanford CS Library link.  There are so many goodies there...

Comment: Harry's response is the opposite of helpful here.

Comment: @Peyman `*p` does not retrieve the data that p points to. Instead it designates the memory location. That expression could then go on to be used to either store new data in, or retrieve data from, or nothing.

Comment: an appropriate example just came into my mind when you delete something from computer memory or you can say from harddisk... actually you delete nothing it just dereference the pointer pointing to the address of file inside memory.

Answer (score 893, accepted):

### Reviewing the basic terminology

It's *usually* good enough - unless you're programming assembly - to envisage a ***pointer*** containing a numeric memory address, with 1 referring to the second byte in the process's memory, 2 the third, 3 the fourth and so on....

- What happened to 0 and the first byte?  Well, we'll get to that later - see *null pointers* below.
- For a more accurate definition of what pointers store, and how memory and addresses relate, see *"More about memory addresses, and why you probably don't need to know"* at the end of this answer.

When you want to access the data/value in the memory that the pointer points to - the contents of the address with that numerical index - then you ***dereference*** the pointer.

Different computer languages have different notations to tell the compiler or interpreter that you're now interested in the pointed-to object's (current) value - I focus below on C and C++.

### A pointer scenario

Consider in C, given a pointer such as `p` below...

```
const char* p = "abc";
```

...four bytes with the numerical values used to encode the letters 'a', 'b', 'c', and a 0 byte to denote the end of the textual data, are stored somewhere in memory and the numerical address of that data is stored in `p`.  This way C encodes text in memory is known as [*ASCIIZ*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).

For example, if the string literal happened to be at address 0x1000 and `p` a 32-bit pointer at 0x2000, the memory content would be:

```
Memory Address (hex)    Variable name    Contents
1000                                     'a' == 97 (ASCII)
1001                                     'b' == 98
1002                                     'c' == 99
1003                                     0
...
2000-2003               p                1000 hex
```

Note that there is no variable name/identifier for address 0x1000, but we can indirectly refer to the string literal using a pointer storing its address: `p`.

### Dereferencing the pointer

To refer to the characters `p` points to, we dereference `p` using one of these notations (again, for C):

```
assert(*p == 'a');  // The first character at address p will be 'a'
assert(p[1] == 'b'); // p[1] actually dereferences a pointer created by adding
                     // p and 1 times the size of the things to which p points:
                     // In this case they're char which are 1 byte in C...
assert(*(p + 1) == 'b');  // Another notation for p[1]
```

You can also move pointers through the pointed-to data, dereferencing them as you go:

```
++p;  // Increment p so it's now 0x1001
assert(*p == 'b');  // p == 0x1001 which is where the 'b' is...
```

If you have some data that can be written to, then you can do things like this:

```
int x = 2;
int* p_x = &x;  // Put the address of the x variable into the pointer p_x
*p_x = 4;       // Change the memory at the address in p_x to be 4
assert(x == 4); // Check x is now 4
```

Above, you must have known at compile time that you would need a variable called `x`, and the code asks the compiler to arrange where it should be stored, ensuring the address will be available via `&x`.

### Dereferencing and accessing a structure data member

In C, if you have a variable that is a pointer to a structure with data members, you can access those members using the `->` dereferencing operator:

```
typedef struct X { int i_; double d_; } X;
X x;
X* p = &x;
p->d_ = 3.14159;  // Dereference and access data member x.d_
(*p).d_ *= -1;    // Another equivalent notation for accessing x.d_
```

### Multi-byte data types

To use a pointer, a computer program also needs some insight into the type of data that is being pointed at - if that data type needs more than one byte to represent, then the pointer normally points to the lowest-numbered byte in the data.

So, looking at a slightly more complex example:

```
double sizes[] = { 10.3, 13.4, 11.2, 19.4 };
double* p = sizes;
assert(p[0] == 10.3);  // Knows to look at all the bytes in the first double value
assert(p[1] == 13.4);  // Actually looks at bytes from address p + 1 * sizeof(double)
                       // (sizeof(double) is almost always eight bytes)
++p;                   // Advance p by sizeof(double)
assert(*p == 13.4);    // The double at memory beginning at address p has value 13.4
*(p + 2) = 29.8;       // Change sizes[3] from 19.4 to 29.8
                       // Note earlier ++p and + 2 here => sizes[3]
```

### Pointers to dynamically allocated memory

Sometimes you don't know how much memory you'll need until your program is running and sees what data is thrown at it... then you can dynamically allocate memory using `malloc`. It is common practice to store the address in a pointer...

```
int* p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); // Get some memory somewhere...
*p = 10;            // Dereference the pointer to the memory, then write a value in
fn(*p);             // Call a function, passing it the value at address p
(*p) += 3;          // Change the value, adding 3 to it
free(p);            // Release the memory back to the heap allocation library
```

In C++, memory allocation is normally done with the `new` operator, and deallocation with `delete`:

```
int* p = new int(10); // Memory for one int with initial value 10
delete p;

p = new int[10];      // Memory for ten ints with unspecified initial value
delete[] p;

p = new int[10]();    // Memory for ten ints that are value initialised (to 0)
delete[] p;
```

See also *C++ smart pointers* below.

### Losing and leaking addresses

Often a pointer may be the only indication of where some data or buffer exists in memory. If ongoing use of that data/buffer is needed, or the ability to call `free()` or `delete` to avoid leaking the memory, then the programmer must operate on a copy of the pointer...

```
const char* p = asprintf("name: %s", name);  // Common but non-Standard printf-on-heap

// Replace non-printable characters with underscores....
for (const char* q = p; *q; ++q)
    if (!isprint(*q))
        *q = '_';

printf("%s\n", p); // Only q was modified
free(p);
```

...or carefully orchestrate reversal of any changes...

```
const size_t n = ...;
p += n;
...
p -= n;  // Restore earlier value...
free(p);
```

### C++ smart pointers

In C++, it's best practice to use [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) objects to store and manage the pointers, automatically deallocating them when the smart pointers' destructors run. Since C++11 the Standard Library provides two, [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) for when there's a single owner for an allocated object...

```
{
    std::unique_ptr<T> p{new T(42, "meaning")};
    call_a_function(p);
    // The function above might throw, so delete here is unreliable, but...
} // p's destructor's guaranteed to run "here", calling delete
```

...and [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) for share ownership (using [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting))...

```
{
    auto p = std::make_shared<T>(3.14, "pi");
    number_storage1.may_add(p); // Might copy p into its container
    number_storage2.may_add(p); // Might copy p into its container    } // p's destructor will only delete the T if neither may_add copied it
```

### Null pointers

In C, `NULL` and `0` - and additionally in C++ `nullptr` - can be used to indicate that a pointer doesn't currently hold the memory address of a variable, and shouldn't be dereferenced or used in pointer arithmetic. For example:

```
const char* p_filename = NULL; // Or "= 0", or "= nullptr" in C++
int c;
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "f:")) != -1)
    switch (c) {
      case f: p_filename = optarg; break;
    }
if (p_filename)  // Only NULL converts to false
    ...   // Only get here if -f flag specified
```

In C and C++, just as inbuilt numeric types don't necessarily default to `0`, nor `bools` to `false`, pointers are not always set to `NULL`. All these are set to 0/false/NULL when they're `static` variables or (C++ only) direct or indirect member variables of static objects or their bases, or undergo zero initialisation (e.g. `new T();` and `new T(x, y, z);` perform zero-initialisation on T's members including pointers, whereas `new T;` does not).

Further, when you assign `0`, `NULL` and `nullptr` to a pointer the bits in the pointer are not necessarily all reset: the pointer may not contain "0" at the hardware level, or refer to address 0 in your virtual address space. The compiler is allowed to store something else there if it has reason to, but whatever it does - if you come along and compare the pointer to `0`, `NULL`, `nullptr` or another pointer that was assigned any of those, the comparison must work as expected. So, below the source code at the compiler level, "NULL" is potentially a bit "magical" in the C and C++ languages...

### More about memory addresses, and why you probably don't need to know

More strictly, initialised pointers store a bit-pattern identifying either `NULL` or a (often [virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space)) memory address.

The simple case is where this is a numeric offset into the process's entire virtual address space; in more complex cases the pointer may be relative to some specific memory area, which the CPU may select based on CPU "segment" registers or some manner of segment id encoded in the bit-pattern, and/or looking in different places depending on the machine code instructions using the address.

For example, an `int*` properly initialised to point to an `int` variable might - after casting to a `float*` - access memory in "GPU" memory quite distinct from the memory where the `int` variable is, then once cast to and used as a function pointer it might point into further distinct memory holding machine opcodes for the program (with the numeric value of the `int*` effectively a random, invalid pointer within these other memory regions).

3GL programming languages like C and C++ tend to hide this complexity, such that:

- If the compiler gives you a pointer to a variable or function, you can dereference it freely (as long as the variable's not destructed/deallocated meanwhile) and it's the compiler's problem whether e.g. a particular CPU segment register needs to be restored beforehand, or a distinct machine code instruction used
- If you get a pointer to an element in an array, you can use pointer arithmetic to move anywhere else in the array, or even to form an address one-past-the-end of the array that's legal to compare with other pointers to elements in the array (or that have similarly been moved by pointer arithmetic to the same one-past-the-end value); again in C and C++, it's up to the compiler to ensure this "just works"
- Specific OS functions, e.g. shared memory mapping, may give you pointers, and they'll "just work" within the range of addresses that makes sense for them
- Attempts to move legal pointers beyond these boundaries, or to cast arbitrary numbers to pointers, or use pointers cast to unrelated types, typically have [*undefined behaviour*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so should be avoided in higher level libraries and applications, but code for OSes, device drivers, etc. may need to rely on behaviour left undefined by the C or C++ Standard, that is nevertheless well defined by their specific implementation or hardware.

Comment: is `p[1] ` and `*(p + 1)` *identical*? That is, Does `p[1] ` and `*(p + 1)` generate the same instructions?

Comment: @Pacerier: from 6.5.2.1/2 in the N1570 draft C Standard (first I found online) "The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))." - I can't imagine any reason why a compiler wouldn't immediately convert them to identical representations in an early stage of compilation, applying the same optimisations after that, but I don't see how anyone can definitely prove the code would be identical without surveying every compiler ever written.

Comment: @TonyD, no I'm not talking about compiler implementations, but rather, did the official standard guarantees that behavior? I mean the latest standards C90, C99, and C11....

Comment: @Pacerier: the Standards are framed in terms of necessary _observable_ behaviours, but how the compilers choose to map source code to machine opcodes is not mandated.

Comment: @Pacerier: Actually, p[1] === *(p + 1) === *(1 + p) === 1[p].
You can get the sixth element in an array by writing: '6[arr]'.
That seems quite identical to me.

Comment: Under your section "Multi-byte data types", wouldn't the last statement be assigning to sizes[3] and not sizes[2], from the increment two lines prior?

Comment: @selkathguy: yikes - in revision 18 I modified it to `[2]` because someone commented that it was wrong and I missed the `++p` myself then - I'd been right the first time.  Will revert.  Thanks!

Comment: I see that the standard prefers the term _indirection_ over _dereferencing_ last years (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3362.html)

Comment: why is `p` at `2000-2003`?! Why isn't it just `2000` containing `1000 hex`?

Comment: @Honey: the value 1000 hex is too big to encode in a single byte (8 bits) of memory: you can only store unsigned numbers from 0 to 255 in one byte.  So, you just can't store 1000 hex at "just" the address 2000.  Instead, a 32-bit system would use 32 bits - which is four bytes - with addresses from 2000 to 2003.  A 64-bit system would use 64 bits - 8 bytes - from 2000 to 2007.  Either way, the base address of `p` is just 2000: if you had another pointer to `p` it would have to store 2000 in its four or eight bytes.  Hope that helps!  Cheers.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: If a union `u` contains an array `arr`, both gcc and clang will recognize that the lvalue `u.arr[i]` might access the same storage as other union members, but will not recognize that lvalue `*(u.arr+i)` might do so.  I'm not sure whether the authors of those compilers think that the latter invokes UB, or that the former invokes UB but they should process it usefully anyway, but they clearly view the two expressions as different.

Comment: @supercat: interesting!  In that space there're all the strict aliasing and active-member-of-union rules, and the allowance for character arrays to be used for aliasing (and hence `memcpy`).  GCC and clang have their `-fno-strict-aliasing` support.  I can't tell from your description whether `arr` or the *"other union members"* in your scenario are character arrays, or whether you're using `-fno-strict-aliasing`, but regardless if does seem bizarre for one notation to work and not the other.  Maybe worth making a question about it?  Cheers

Comment: @TonyDelroy: The Standard treats the ability to access a struct or union object using an lvalue of any type other than the struct/union type or a character type as a Quality of Implementation issue.  It makes no attempt to say what constructs quality implementations intended for various purposes *should* support.  GCC and Clang behave as quality implementations when various optimizations are disabled, but unfortunately the authors regard code that's intended for use on quality compilers as "broken".

Comment: @supercat: well, sounds like you side with Linus on that....  I find it hard to get excited about, given specifying `-fno-strict-aliasing` isn't particularly onerous.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: So far as I can tell, there is no meaningful specification that describes what operations are guaranteed to work in `-fstrict-aliasing` mode.  The Standard is useless in that regard, since even an ordinary struct member access lvalue invokes UB.  It's possible to use `-fno-strict-aliasing` to be sure, but if the design of gcc makes it necessary to use `-fno-strict-aliasing` to be certain code will work then any effort the authors put into aliasing optimizations is wasted and could be better spent elsewhere.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: A bigger issue is that there's no way to tell the compiler not to optimize in any ways that version ___ didn't, and thus no way someone can make a build file that can be expected, with reasonable certainty, to be compatible with future versions of the compiler except by disabling most optimizations wholesale.  Otherwise, from what I can tell, the gcc maintainers' attitude is that they think there is nothing wrong with arbitrarily breaking any of the 99% of programs that rely upon any kind of "Quality of Implementation" UB.

Comment: I've rarely seen pointers and their use within C/C++ so concisely and simply explained.

Comment: @supercat: It's a big topic (too big to cover properly in comments here).  Quite agree that GCC and clang should document what's made safe by `-fno-strict-aliasing`, and minimise regressions between releases.  In this space, I believe C++20 is still expected to add [`bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast), which will hopefully replace some of the `reinterpret_cast` and union based type punning UBs.  *"even an ordinary struct member access lvalue invokes UB"* - could you elaborate or provide a link re this one?  Cheers

Comment: @TonyDelroy: What's needed for safety and optimization isn't so much a "bit cast" operator, but rather a "restricted pointer" type which during its lifetime requires that all parts of an object that are accessed using a restricted pointer be accessed exclusively through it, and whose constructor could take a pointer of any type and cause accesses made through the restricted pointer to be treated as accesses to the original type.  Most code that needs to use type punning would be amenable to such a construct, and it would allow many useful optimizations that would go beyond TBAA.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: In the C11 Standard, given `struct S {int x;} s;`, the type of lvalue `s.x` is `int`, but the only types of lvalue that can be used to access the stored value of a `struct S` are `struct S` and character types.  I think the authors of the Standard thought it sufficiently obvious that any non-broken compiler should handle cases like `s.x` that they didn't need to explicitly specify it, but they probably thought the same about a number of access patterns that the authors of gcc and clang seem to take pride in refusing to support without `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

Answer (score 134):

Dereferencing a pointer means getting the value that is stored in the memory location pointed by the pointer. The operator * is used to do this, and is called the dereferencing operator.

```
int a = 10;
int* ptr = &a;

printf("%d", *ptr); // With *ptr I'm dereferencing the pointer. 
                    // Which means, I am asking the value pointed at by the pointer.
                    // ptr is pointing to the location in memory of the variable a.
                    // In a's location, we have 10. So, dereferencing gives this value.

// Since we have indirect control over a's location, we can modify its content using the pointer. This is an indirect way to access a.

 *ptr = 20;         // Now a's content is no longer 10, and has been modified to 20.
```

Comment: A pointer doesn't point to a *value*, it points to an *object*.

Comment: @KeithThompson A pointer does not point to an object, it points to a memory address, where an object (maybe a primitive) is located.

Comment: @mg30rg: I'm not sure what distinction you're making. A pointer value *is* an address. An object, by definition, is a "region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values". And what do you mean by "primitive"? The C standard doesn't use that term.

Comment: @KeithThompson I was barely pointing out, that you did not actually add value to the answer, you were only nitpicking on terminology (and did that wrong also). The pointer value surely is an address, that's how it "points" to a memory address. The word "object" in our OOPdriven world can be misleading, because it can be interpreted as "class instance" (yep, I was not aware that the question is labeled [C] and not [C++]), and I used the word "primitive" as in the opposite of "copmlex" (data structure like a struct or class).

Comment: @mg30rg: I stand by my original statement: A pointer doesn't point to a value, it points to an object. And the question was updated to correct that. Terminology is important, and no, I don't believe I got anything wrong. Incidentally, the C++ standard's definition of the word "object" is very similar to C's, and has nothing to do with OOP. By "primitive", it sounds like mean what the standard calls "scalar"; yes the object pointed to by a pointer may or may not be of scalar type, but I'm not sure that adds anything.

Comment: Let me add to this answer that the array subscript operator `[]` also dereferences a pointer (`a[b]` is defined to mean `*(a + b)`).

Comment: @cmaster: The Standard may define that equivalence, but both gcc and clang treat `someUnion.array[i]` and `*(someUnion.array+i)` differently, recognizing accesses upon the former, but not the latter, as accesses to the union object.

Comment: @supercat I don't know what you mean by "recognizing accesses". What I'm talking about is the fact, that when you write either `someUnion.array[i]` or `*(someUnion.array + i)`, you a) name an array (`someUnion.array`), you b) decay that array into a pointer, and you c) access the bytes behind that pointer. Step b) may be omitted if `someUnion.array` is not an array itself but rather a pointer to some dynamic memory, but the rest is identical in all cases.

Comment: @cmaster: Given something like `if (u.arr1[i]) u.arr2[j]=1; return u.arr[i]`, gcc and clang will return the value that `u.arr1[i]` holds when the function returns.  Change the code to `if (*(u.arr1+i)) *(u.arr2+j)=1; return *(u.arr1+i);` and they'll return the value that `u.arr1[i]` held when the condition was tested, even if the write to `u.arr2[j]` modified `u.arr1[i]`.

Comment: @supercat That's because the `return u.arr[i]` is firmly within UB territory after executing `u.arr2[j] = 1`. After all, you are reading a union member after writing to another one. The compiler could decide to return a pink elephant instead. So it's of little use to muse over what it actually returned...

Comment: @cmaster: C99 specifies that writing one union member and reading another will reinterpret the bits.  If the write produced a bit pattern that would be a trap representation for the read type, that would invoke UB, but uint16_t and uint32_t are forbidden from having trap representations

Answer (score 25):

In simple words, dereferencing means accessing the value from a certain memory location against which that pointer is pointing.

Answer (score 23):

A pointer is a "reference" to a value.. much like a library call number is a reference to a book. "Dereferencing" the call number is physically going through and retrieving that book.

```
int a=4 ;
int *pA = &a ;
printf( "The REFERENCE/call number for the variable `a` is %p\n", pA ) ;

// The * causes pA to DEREFERENCE...  `a` via "callnumber" `pA`.
printf( "%d\n", *pA ) ; // prints 4..
```

If the book isn't there, the librarian starts shouting, shuts the library down, and a couple of people are set to investigate the cause of a person going to find a book that isn't there.

Answer (score 8):

Code and explanation from [Pointer Basics](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/):

> The dereference operation starts at
>   the pointer and follows its arrow over
>   to access its pointee. The goal may be
>   to look at the pointee state or to
>   change the pointee state. The
>   dereference operation on a pointer
>   only works if the pointer has a
>   pointee -- the pointee must be
>   allocated and the pointer must be set
>   to point to it. The most common error
>   in pointer code is forgetting to set
>   up the pointee. The most common
>   runtime crash because of that error in
>   the code is a failed dereference
>   operation. In Java the incorrect
>   dereference will be flagged politely
>   by the runtime system. In compiled
>   languages such as C, C++, and Pascal,
>   the incorrect dereference will
>   sometimes crash, and other times
>   corrupt memory in some subtle, random
>   way. Pointer bugs in compiled
>   languages can be difficult to track
>   down for this reason.

```
void main() {   
    int*    x;  // Allocate the pointer x
    x = malloc(sizeof(int));    // Allocate an int pointee,
                            // and set x to point to it
    *x = 42;    // Dereference x to store 42 in its pointee   
}
```

Comment: You actually have to allocate memory for where x is supposed to point at. Your example has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I think all the previous answers are wrong, as they
state that dereferencing means accessing the actual value.
Wikipedia gives the correct definition instead:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator

> It operates on a pointer variable, and returns an l-value equivalent to the value at the pointer address. This is called "dereferencing" the pointer.

That said, we can dereference the pointer without ever
accessing the value it points to. For example:

```
char *p = NULL;
*p;
```

We dereferenced the NULL pointer without accessing its
value. Or we could do:

```
p1 = &(*p);
sz = sizeof(*p);
```

Again, dereferencing, but never accessing the value. Such code will NOT crash:
The crash happens when you actually *access* the data by an
invalid pointer. However, unfortunately, according the the
standard, dereferencing an invalid pointer is an undefined
behaviour (with a few exceptions), even if you don't try to
touch the actual data.

So in short: dereferencing the pointer means applying the
dereference operator to it. That operator just returns an
l-value for your future use.

Comment: well,you dereferenced a NULL pointer ,that would lead to segmentation fault.

Comment: on top of that you searched for 'dereferencing operator' and not 'dereferencing a pointer' which actually means getting the value/accessing a value at a memory location being pointed to by a pointer.

Comment: Have you tried? I did. The following does not crash:

`    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        char *p = NULL;
        *p;
        return 0;
    }
`

Comment: @stsp Does because the code doesn't crash now doesn't mean that it won't in future, or on some other system.

Comment: The question was about what dereferencing the pointer
means. Whether it can theoretically crash or not when you
dereference the pointer w/o touching the actual memory
location, is out of the question's scope. On any common
arches and compilers this won't crash.

Comment: `int arr[5]={0};int (*p)[5] = &arr` Why `*p` is the address of the array?I know `*p` is `int [5]` type, but `p` stores the address of array. Since dereference p, I thought it will be `0`, the value of arr[0].  Coz that's what stores in the address indicated by p.

Comment: `*p;` causes undefined behaviour. Although you are right that dereferencing does not access the value *per se*, the code `*p;` *does* access the value.

Comment: Please prove your claims. Dereferencing has nothing to do with accessing the value, as I already explained in my main answer. `operator =` is what accesses the value, and in `*p;` there is no `operator =`, only a dereferencing op. It doesn't access the value. Some compilers provide the "volatile dummy read" feature that inserts the fetch if `p` was marked volatile.

Comment: @stsp: proof from the C Standard: *"...If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer,the behavior of the unary `*` operator is undefined."* - with footnote *"Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary `*` operator are a null pointer [...]"*  So `*p` on a null pointer has *undefined behaviour* - all bets are off.  That could manifest in many unfortunate ways - not just an attempt to read from address 0, but - for example - removing code unconditionally executing `*p` on NULL, based on the (legal) deduction it can't be meant to run given it has undefined behaviour.

Comment: You're right about `&(*p)` though - the C Standard defines that as equivalent to `p`, explicitly even for NULL: *"Thus, `&*E` is equivalent to `E` (even if `E` is a null pointer)"*

Comment: I was not questioning the "undefined behaviour" part of the claim.
He said "*p; does access the value", and that was wrong.