# Unhandled exception at 0x009f240e in OpenGL and GLUT - 101.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, dereference, null-pointer

I keep getting the following error: Unhandled exception at 0x009f240e in OpenGL and GLUT - 101.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

I have found some questions here with a similar error code but they all seem to say the problem is: dereferencing a NULL pointer.  However, I can't seem to find anything that really explains what that means or what to do about it.

Here is a small sample of my code:

```
Tree* myTree; //global variable pointer

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{   
      fstream file = fstream ("Tree.txt");

      *myTree = Tree(file);   // This is where the error is occuring
}
```

If anyone has any advice or ideas on what I could do to fix this, please let me know.  If there is any other code I should add, let me know that as well.

Comment: Well, check if `file` is opened/valid.

Comment: @KirilKirov, the problem is the `*myTree`.

Comment: Please, please, please. Consider reading at least a basic C and/or C++ book before asking questions like this. You dereference a null pointer, it is obvious what the problem is even from error message you get, you even add a null-pointer tag, yet still you ask it here...

Comment: @Vlad: It's not luck, global variables are guaranteed to be initialized to 0 at program start.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: You are right, corrected. But the point still remains :)

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
*myTree = Tree(file);
```

is writing to un-allocated memory, by dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. It seems the pointer points to 0, which explains the exception at that address.

Comment: `myTree` is not uninitialized -- global variables are always guaranteed to be initialized to 0 at program start.

Comment: I understand that the issue is that I am trying to dereference a null pointer.  What I don't understand is what this means or how to allocate memory for a pointer of an object.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Isn't that only true for `static` variables?

Comment: @unwind: No, all objects at global scope are zero-initialized, regardless of whether they have internal linkage (`static`) or external linkage (`extern`).  See C++03 §3.6.2/1 (Initialization of non-local objects) `[basic.start.init]`.

Answer (score 0):

I will guess that what you are trying to do is create an instance of `Tree` and have the global pointer `myTree` point to it.

If that is the case, your problem is in the syntax you use to create and assign that instance. `*myTree` actually [dereferences the pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean), and you try to assign it to a copy of `Tree(file)`

What you need to do is create an instance of `Tree` with the `new` operator, and assign the return value (which is a pointer to the newly created instance) to the pointer myTree (as opposed to the dereferenced *myTree).

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{   
      fstream file = fstream ("Tree.txt");

      myTree = new Tree(file);   // Create a new instance of Tree and store its pointer in myTree
}
```

Don't forget to free the memory created by the `operator new` by calling `delete` on `myTree` when you're done with it.