# Print bytes of a void pointer

Tags: c, void-pointers, bit

If I create a void pointer, and malloc a section of memory to that void pointer, how can I print out the individual bytes that I just allocated?

For example:

```
void * p;
p = malloc(24);
printf("0x%x\n", (int *)p);
```

I would like the above to print the 24 bytes that I just allocated.

Comment: You allocated 24 *bytes*, actually. (Strictly speaking, you allocated space to hold 24 characters.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
size_t size = 24;
void *p = malloc(size);

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  printf("%02x", ((unsigned char *) p) [i]);
}
```

Of course it invokes undefined behavior (the value of an object allocated by `malloc` has an indeterminate value).

Comment: +1, but perhaps you could leave out that comment on undefined behavior. It's already implicit in the question. The OP wants to know what the memory looks like right after `malloc`.

Comment: @s.bandara Why is it implicit? OP doesn't seem to even know about it.

Comment: @s.bandara I need it otherwise somebody will downvote this answer because it invokes undefined behavior ;)

Comment: That's what I thought, it looks like a CYA sentence, and I think it should go away. @H2CO3, if the goal is to inspect the memory allocated by `malloc` it is not even undefined behavior in that sense. Rather, the result will be undetermined, but so is the behavior of `scanf`, for example.

Comment: Indeterminate value doesn't mean undefined behavior. Does it? Sure you can read anything, but it won't cause your program to go crazy.

Comment: @s.bandara Euh, no. It **is undefined behavior.** I do know the difference between undefined behavior and unspecified [behavior | result | value | order of evaluation]. And this **is** defined to invoke UB.

Comment: @s.bandara reading an indeterminate value invokes undefined behavior : *undefined behavior: Behavior upon use of a non portable or erroneous program construct of erroneous data or of indeterminately valued object*

Comment: Guys, all I have to say is that you should apply that definition in this particular context. You can look at memory before initialization using a debugger, which is doing exactly the same thing, but so what? "undefined behavior" is not meaningful in such a context.

Comment: @s.bandara but a debugger is not a C implementation, so undefined behavior does not apply to a debugger.

Comment: Strictly speaking, accessing an indeterminate value isn't always undefined behavior (and the above example isn't UB). C99 defines "indeterminate value" as "either an unspecified value or a trap representation".  Since accessing memory through a character type cannot result in a trap representation, accessing an indeterminate value through a character type isn't undefined behavior - you'll just read unspecified values.

Comment: @MichaelBurr strictly speaking reading an indeterminate value is always UB (so even if you read an `unsigned char` object and we know `unsigned char` objecst do not have trap representations). See DR#338 http:// http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_338.htm

Comment: @ouah: so I see that C11 (due to that DR) added UB behavior for reading though a character type in certain situations - however the 'new' UB only applies to accessing an automatic that has never had its address taken. A `malloc()`'ed block doesn't fall into that category. So I think that your example is still not UB.

Answer (score 2):

***You can't*** - reading those bytes before initializing their contents leads to undefined behavior. If you really insist on doing this, however, try this:

```
void *buf = malloc(24);
unsigned char *ptr = buf;
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    printf("%02x ", (int)ptr[i]);
}

free(buf);
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void print_memory(void *ptr, int size)
{ // Print 'size' bytes starting from 'ptr'
    unsigned char *c = (unsigned char *)ptr;
    int i = 0;

    while(i != size)
        printf("%02x ", c[i++]);           
}
```

As H2CO3 mentioned, using uninitialized data results in undefined behavior, but the above snipped should do what want. Call:

```
print_memory(p, 24);
```

Comment: Without incrementing i, that wont ever return.

Answer (score 1):

`void* p = malloc(24);` allocates 24 bytes and stores the address of first byte in `p`. If you try to print the value of `p`, you'll be actually printing the address. To print the value your pointer points to, you need to dereference it by using `*`. Also try to avoid `void` pointers if possible:

```
unsigned char *p = malloc(24);
// store something to the memory where p points to...
for(int i = 0; i < 24; ++i)
    printf("%02X", *(p + i));
```

And don't forget to `free` the memory that has been allocated by `malloc` :)

This question could help you too: [What does "dereferencing" a pointer mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean)

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` allocates in bytes and not in bits.  And whatever it is, your `printf` is trying to print an address in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

The malloc allocates bytes.

```
 for (i = 0; i < 24; ++i) printf("%02xh ", p[i]);
```

would print the 24 bytes. But if cast to an int, you'll need to adjust the loop:

```
 for (i = 0; i < 24; i += sizeof(int)) printf("%xh", *(int *)&p[i]);
```

But then, if you know you want an int, why not just declare it as an int?

Comment: I'll admit that no, I do not understand pointer arithmetic. I need to use a void pointer due to the specifications of a larger assignment.

Comment: @kubiej21 I was directing this one to the author of this answer.

Comment: Ok, so a typo gets a snide remark? Are you sure you understand interacting with humans?