# Pointer dereference in an assignment

Tags: c, pointers, variable-assignment

I was watching a lecture and got confused at a point when professor said
that  `ptr=&x` denotes a variable `ptr` assigned the address of the variable `x`.
And for `y=*ptr+1`  he said `*ptr` denotes the value stored at `x` (or the value of `x`).
I became slightly confused here as `*ptr` should be pointing towards the address of `x` right, not the value stored at `x`? Can  someone please elaborate it a bit more?

Comment: `*ptr` refers to the entry stored at `ptr`. See here for an explanation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29#C_pointers

Comment: `ptr` refers to the address of the variable `x`. `*ptr` refers to the value in memory at the address of `x`. `*ptr = *(&x) = x`.

Comment: This is a question about a the behavior concrete piece of C code, not about the semantics of the C language. It is a programming question and not a computer science question, so I am migrating it to [so].

Comment: You must see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean)

Answer (score 6):

Consider,

```
int a = 10;
```

Now, in memory we have something like

```
                   +------+
                   |      |
                   |  10  |
                   |      |
                   +------+
               0x121  a
```

Now, consider a pointer variable of type `int`

```
int* ap = &a;
```

This looks like,

```
                +-------+
                |       |
                |  10   |
                |       |
          0x121 +-------+
                    a  

                +-------+ 
                |       |     
                | 0x121 |
                |       |
                +-------+
                   ap
```

`a` is a label to the memory location and `ap` is the address. To get the value at that address you use `*`. This is called dereferencing the pointer.

```
*ap
```

This gives you `10`

Read some good [tutorial](http://boredzo.org/pointers/) on pointer.

Answer (score 2):

It is `ptr` that points to `x`, not `*ptr`. `*ptr` is not even a pointer (assuming `x` isn't one).

The variable `ptr` contains a pointer to the variable `x`, i.e. the address of the variable `x`. The value of the expression `ptr` is a pointer to `x`. The value of the expression `*ptr` is the value at the location that `ptr` points to: that's what the dereference operator `*` means. Since `ptr` points to `x`, the value of `*ptr` is the value of `x`.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer points to an address where a value is stored.

```
int *ptr;
int x = 2;
ptr = &x;
```

Here, ptr is an int pointer and x is an int (obviously). If we want ptr to "keep track" of the value of x then we assign ptr the *address* of x. So when we dereference ptr we get the value stored at the address that ptr points to. So if we want to change the value that ptr "stores" then we dereference it.

```
*ptr = 5;
```

This changes the value at the address ptr points to from 2 to 5.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
int x = 42;
int *ptr = &x;
```

`x` is an integer object (of type `int`), and `ptr` is a pointer object (of type `int*` or *pointer-to-`int`*).

Unary `&` is the address operator. Applying it to an object of type `FOO` gives you the address of that object (or, equivalently, a pointer to that object); that address/pointer value is of type `FOO*`, or *pointer-to-`FOO`*. The operand of unary `&` must be the name of an object, not just a value; `&42` is illegal nonsense. (The symbol `&` is also used for the binary bitwise *and* operator, which is completely unrelated to the address operator.)

Unary `*` is the *dereference* operator, the inverse of `&`. Its operand must be value of some pointer type. `*ptr` refers to the object to which `ptr` points.

Given the above declarations, and assuming the value of `ptr` hasn't been changed, the expressions `x` and `*ptr` mean the same thing; they both refer to the same `int` object (whose value happens to be 42).  Similarly, the expressions `&x` and `ptr` mean the same thing; they both yield the address of `x`, an address that has been stored in the pointer object `ptr`.

It's important to note that `*ptr` doesn't just refer to the current *value* of `x`, it refers to the object `x` itself -- just like the name `x` does. If you use `*ptr` in a value context, this doesn't matter; you'll just get the value of `x`. But if you use it on the left side of an assignment, for example, it doesn't evaluate to `42`. It evaluates to the object `x` itself, and lets you modify that object. (The distinction here is whether `*ptr` is used as an *lvalue*.)

Comment: Is there a mistake in the first excerpt

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Not anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The variable `ptr` stores the *address* of `x`.  To retrieve the value stored at `x`, we *dereference* `ptr` with the unary `*` operator; hence, the *expression* `*ptr` evaluates to the value of `x`.

Put another way, if

```
 p == &x;
```

then

```
*p == x;
```