# is this a pointer or is it mulitiplying int type with arg?

Tags: c

i understand this being pointer *();
but *((type *)type); is whats confusing me

I have tried to understand pointers but its confusing me.

```
int offset = *((int *)arg);
```

Comment: Its called pointer dereferencing - this question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this down:

```
(int *)arg;
```

This takes `arg` and casts it to an `int *`. The result of this expression is, of course, an `int *`.

```
*((int *)arg);
```

We're now just dereferencing that `int *` we just came up with — the result is the integer that the pointer was pointing to.

```
int offset = *((int *)arg);
```

We assign that integer into offeset.

No multiplication is involved here.

Comment: oh so arg is basically storing the address that the int * was pointing to or the value when its dereferenced ?

Comment: We can't see the type of arg, so it's hard to say exactly what it is storing. Since we're casting it to an `int *`, hopefully it's a pointer type (and thus storing an address). Typically, the reason to perform that cast is because `arg` is a `void *`, and you have some  knowledge that it points to an integer. (And is thus safe to cast.)

Answer (score 1):

This `(int *)arg` takes whatever type `arg` is and pretends it is a `int *`

This `*((int *)arg)` takes the above pointer and deferences it, returning an `int`

Answer (score 0):

You are casting `arg` to a pointer to int which is then dereferenced.

Think of it this way:

```
void* arg;
int* ptr = (int*) arg;
int offset = *ptr;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a cast followed by a dereference. Basically, you're telling the compiler, "Trust me. I know that `arg` points to an `int`, so read the `int` it's pointing to, and put it into `offset`.