# how do I compare a char pointer and a car in C

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have a char pointer that holds a single character. I want to create a while loop that will continue to run as long as that character is not '~'. But I cannot seem to get the characters to compare correctly.

```
char *currChar;
while(currChar != '~') {
    //read();
    printf("Current Char:%c\n", currChar);
}
```

read puts the last value entered by the user into currChar. The printF will always output the correct information (i.e. a ~ if the user pressed ~) but for some reason he while loop will never be exited.

If i try to do something like while(*currChar != '~') I get a segmentation fault error.

What can I do to get this to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `char*` pointer does not *contain* a single `char`. It may *point to* a single `char`. That `char` object is `*currChar`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "dereferencing" a pointer mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean)

Comment: I doubt this segfaults.

Comment: BTW, I would not use `read()` as the function name, since it is a Posix function. try `getchar()`

Answer (score 1):

Your char pointer does *not* hold a single character.  It points to a single character in memory.  You need to declare an actual `char` somewhere.

E.g.,

```
char currChar = ' ';  /* Initialize to something not '~' */
while( currChar != '~' ) {
    /* read().  If your read function requires a pointer, then provide &currChar. */
    printf("Current character: %c\n", currChar);
}
```

So what's wrong with your code is that `char *currChar;` creates an uninitialized pointer.  That pointer is not pointing anywhere.  You could do this:

```
char currChar = ' ';
char *currChar_ptr = &currChar;
```

Now you have a character.  And your pointer is pointing to that character.

Comment: This is an infinite loop

Comment: @self:  It's pseudo code copied directly from the OP's pseudo code.  The idea is that in the commented code area, there is a function that reads a character.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare *currChar.  But the reason you get a segfault is because the first time you compare *currChar to '~', you are comparing an undefined pointer to '~'.

So call read(); before you enter the loop, and make sure you allocate space to store your char in the first place.

Or:

```
char *currChar = '_';

do {
    // read();
    printf("Current Char:%c\n", currChar);
} while (*currChar != '~');
```

Comment: The read() method call is from the code he posted.  Neither you nor I know what this read() is or whether it should or should not have arguments.

Comment: Its irrelevant to the question.  He already said his `read()` method is working correctly.

Comment: `read()` was commented out of the code OP posted, but you think it's relevant, so explain it.

Comment: And?  Why is this confusing to you?  His issue was how to compare a char* to a char literal, not how to read a char from input.

Comment: Stop bickering. This is not helpful to either you or the OP. I just commented out read() to make it match the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the user input before you enter the loop.

This code works:

```
char *currChar;
do{
    read();
    printf("Current Char:%c\n", *currChar);
    currChar++;
}while(*currChar != '~')
```

Comment: `read()` without arguments? `currChar++` ? Is that "hit and hope"?

Comment: I though `read()` was an OP function. And what is the problem with `currChar++` i just increment the pointer! Is that a problem?