# What exactly happens when I use * before a pointer?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object

When you "de-pointer" a pointer to access it as if it were an object using the * operator right before the object's name, what exactly is it doing?

I ask this because I have pointers to objects that store a lot of data and I don't want C++ to copy it or do anything expensive. There's a fine line between me being able to copy this object and using the functions in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an lvalue referring to the object located at the address given by the pointer.

In general, dereferencing a pointer alone will never cause a copy. A copy occurs when the reference obtained is used to construct a new object of the same type (which happens implicitly when passing by value to a function), or used as the argument to an assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

when you dereference a pointer you are just accessing its element; you are not copying anything. These two calls do the same thing:

```
(*p).element = 1;
p->element = 1;
```

if you want a thorough explanation; you might take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4955198/2082964)

Answer (score 0):

> The dereference operator or indirection operator, denoted by "*" (i.e.
>   an asterisk), is a unary operator found in C-like languages that
>   include pointer variables. It operates on a pointer variable, and
>   returns an l-value equivalent to the value at the pointer address.
>   This is called "dereferencing" the pointer.

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator)

When you use pointers to point an object the pointers just point to the address of the object but it doesn't copy anything.....

Answer (score 0):

`'*' returns the object as an l-value this pointer is pointing`. It's as simple as that.