# when you declare a static variable in c

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

when you are declaring static variables in C,

say you wrote a program as such:

```
int *c;
void foo(){
    c = (int *) malloc (10*sizeof(int));
    c = &c[3];
    *c = *&c[3];
}
```

What does it mean to have `*c`? I mean I understand that `*` means that it points to something but what does `*c` do?

and also, why do you need to cast `(int *)` the return value of `malloc()`?

Comment: 1. Study the basics of the language. It will take you decades to learn one trivial question at a time. 2. This has no relation to static variables.

Comment: do you recommend any website to learn the basics of c juanchopanza?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when you are declaring static variables in C

Not related to this question, or atleast to the code you've shown.

> but what does *c do?

Assuming your question related to the statement `*c = *&c[3];`, it refers to the *object at address* held by `c`.

> why did you have to cast (int *) in front of malloc?

You should not. Please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` [and family].

<sup>Note: You code snippet is very poor and bad practice, most likely to be invalid. `c = &c[3];` obvious memory leak.</sup>

Comment: then what kind of variable is "int *c;"?

Comment: @PeterChung `c` is a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: Thank @Quentin for the fix and the answer to OP's latest question. (_Frankly speaking, I'm a bit surprised to see how/why I myself did not answer that. Confused._)

Answer (score 0):

> I mean I understand that * means that it points to something but what does *c do?

The * does not always mean that it point to something.
Example:
If you write this:

```
int* c;
```

It means c is a pointer points to an int variable.

When you do like this:

```
int* c = &x;
*c = 5;
```

The second * is pointer c [dereference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean)