# Need to use BOOL* instead of BOOL

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, pointers, boolean

I am making a chess game in Objective-C. In this game I need to use `BOOL*` instead of `BOOL` because I need a pointer to a boolean variable. When I try to use BOOL*, it gives me a warning when I try to do this:

```
BOOL *isWhiteTurn;
isWhiteTurn = YES;
```

The **warning** is:

> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'BOOL *' (aka
>   'signed char *') from 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char')

Comment: *Why* do you need a pointer? Some more context would be helpful.

Comment: Double check about whether you need a `BOOL*` or a "boxed" BOOL `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean

Comment: You should not use pointers unless you know what they are!!

Comment: If you _need_ to use a pointer, then the computer _needs_ you to use it correctly. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I am using pointers because I am setting the BOOL's value in some other class and I want it to reflect changes everywhere.

Comment: Down-votes here seem excessive.  OP might or might not need a BOOL*, and needs syntax help in any case.  It might be a dup, but the cited dup is too general, imo.  (or it's a dup of every question about c pointers).

Comment: @AdnanZahid: It would really help if you show the relevant code. Where/how is the value set in some other class? Perhaps you just want to pass the *address* ( `&isWhiteTurn` ) to another function?

Comment: @AdnanZahid - It sounds like that other class should have a BOOL property, not a BOOL*.  Everyone with a handle to the same instance of that other class will have a pointer to the same structure... they will all see the current values of its properties, including its scalar properties.

Comment: @MartinR thank you so much! Your solution worked. I passed &isWhiteTurn to another function and it worked. Could you write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @danh - It's down-voted, I suspect, because the question expresses ignorance of a *very* basic concept of C programming that anyone should understand **before** they embark on learning Objective-C.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the information about your problem that's come out in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it became apparent in the comments, you have some function
taking a `BOOL *` parameter, for example

```
void foo(BOOL *boolPtr) {
    *boolPtr = NO;
}
```

and you need to pass the *address* of your `BOOL` variable to
that function:

```
BOOL isWhiteTurn = YES;
foo(&isWhiteTurn);
// Now isWhiteTurn == NO
```

Answer (score 5):

A pointer is exactly what is sounds like, it *points* to some other memory.

Lets take this simple example:

```
BOOL actualVariable = FALSE;
BOOL *pointerVariable = &actualVariable;
```

That makes `pointerVariable` point to `actualVariable`. Using the derefernece operator (unary `*`) you can get the value of what a pointer points to:

```
printf("Value of *pointerVariable = %d\n", *pointerVariable);
```

That should print

```
Value of *pointerVariable = 0
```

More graphically you can look at it this way:

```
+-----------------+       +----------------+
| pointerVariable | ----> | actualVariable |
+-----------------+       +----------------+
```

You can also use the dereference operator to change the value of where the pointer points:

```
*pointerVariable = TRUE;
```

If you declare a pointer, and don't make it point anywhere, then attempting to dereference the pointer (i.e. get what the pointer points to) will result in [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

Now regarding your *warning*. A pointer variable is actually a simple integer, whose value is the address of where it points. That means you can in theory assign any integer value to it, and the program will think that the value is an address of something valid. Most of the time it is *not* something valid though.

You get the warning because usually using an integer value to initialize a pointer is the wrong thing to do, you should initialize the pointer with another pointer to the same type.

Comment: "You get the warning because usually using an integer value to initialize a pointer is the wrong thing to do, you should initialize the pointer with another pointer to the same type.", I am not sure what you mean by this. How should I initialize the BOOL pointer to YES? I mean in code.

Comment: @AdnanZahid See the first code lines. You need to make the pointer actually point somewhere, then you can modify the value of where it points. You can't set the value directly using the pointer, you need to set it *indirectly*.

Comment: Okay, I did "BOOL temp = YES; BOOL *isWhiteTurn = &temp;". Now when I try to do isWhiteTurn = !isWhiteTurn; I am getting a warning "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'BOOL *' (aka 'signed char *') from 'int'"

Comment: @AdnanZahid I think a more appropriate response actually is: ***Why*** do you want to use pointers for this?

Comment: @AdnanZahid Read my answer again, it tells you how to *dereference* the pointer.

Comment: Because I am setting the BOOL's value in some other class and I want it to reflect changes everywhere. I'm trying your dereferencing solution, lets see how it goes :)