# difference between (int *) (&a[2]) and *(&a[2])

Tags: c++, pointers

I have trouble in understanding the difference between the two: (int *) (&a[2]) and *(&a[2]). I understand &a[2] gets the address of a[2] and *gets the value in that address, so *(&a[2]) get the value of a[2], which is 3. But how come (int *)(&a[2]) returns an address? Thank you!

Output:

```
3
0x7fff40144888
```

Codes:

```
include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        int a[3]={1,2,3};
        //cout << *(a+2) << endl;
        cout << *(&a[2]) << endl;
        cout << (int*)(&a[2]) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*(&a[2])` gets the value `a[2]` (a simple reference then dereference)

`(int*)(&a[2])` gets the address of `a[2]` and casts it to an int* (no dereference)

The `(int*)` does not deference the pointer, it casts it to an `int*` (which is redundant since it already is an `int*`)

**Note:** `int*` is a type, just as `int` is a type.

Answer (score 4):

The `( int*)`  is doing c style casting.

All the following 3 statements are going to print same result and they are equivalent in your example's context:

```
    cout << (int*)(&a[2]) << endl;
    cout << &a[2] << endl;
    cout <<static_cast<int*>( &a[2]) << endl;
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c95796c19750400b

Comment: `static_cast` +1 for proper C++

Answer (score 3):

`*`  **will [dereference a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198)**

`(int*)` **is a C-style cast to `int*`**.

---

Since `(&a[2])` produces a pointer to the number `3`...

`*      (&a[2])` will dereference the pointer.

`(int*) (&a[2])` will cast the pointer to an `int` pointer.  (Which it already is - so it has no effect)

Comment: @MattMcNabb you're a hair faster than I am... :)

Answer (score 1):

The first one (`*(&a[2])`) says get the element at index 2 of `a`, get a pointer to that element (aka the address in memory) (`&`), and then get the value at that address (`*`), so essentially the `&` and `*` operators cancel out and you get `a[2]` which is 3.

The second one (`(int*)(&a[2])`) says get the element at index 2 of `a`, get a pointer to that element (`&`), and then cast that pointer to be an int pointer (`(int *)`) (i.e. interpret the value at that address as an integer). So the entire expression will give you the address in memory of `a[2]`, which happens to be `0x7fff40144888`.

Comment: "which happens to be 0x7fff40144888" - lol as if it's going to be the same for everyone

Comment: I mean that in this particular instance of executing the program it happens to be 0x7fff40144888, of course it's not the same for everyone / across executions...