# Dereferencing multi-level pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers, dereference

This may be a duplicate of some other question/answer (which I couldn't find), but it seems to me that there are good explanations of *why and when* to use multi-pointers, but a simple explanation of how **a pointer to a pointer** is *dereferenced* is missing.

I have tried to make a simple (and vague) explanation, which should only give the reader the most basic knowledge of how to dereference *pointers to pointers to pointers to ......*

Answer (score 3):

Such an explanation shouldn't be needed. As you know that `*` dereferences the pointer, it's a simple induction that if the variable pointed to is a pointer, too, you can just dereference *twice* to get to **this** value. And so on.

Don't forget a simple rule of thumb: If you *ever* need more than double indirection (e.g. find yourself writing `***` or worse), *most likely* your design is flawed and you should take one step back, redesign the solution to your problem and then implement again.

Comment: The intention was to give an easy understandable explanation of reading code containing multi-level pointers. Not necessarily something you've designed yourself - (since you should know what a multi-level pointer are before you can use it yourself).

Comment: And I'd still argue that isn't needed. Given the information that `*` dereferences a pointer (along with what *dereference* means) and that pointers may point to other pointers, anyone not capable to deduce he can just write `**` doesn't qualify as a programmer. But that's just my opinion...

Comment: It is obviously opinion against opinion but my experience is that some new programmers (which I know uses this site a lot) have a hard time grasping the concept of pointers and it is not that rare that you stumble across multi-level pointers when you are learning programming.

Comment: @MaltePedersen Playing with multiple levels of indirection is perfectly fine, and should in fact be done, when learning. Felix is talking about production code.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the following code:

```
int *p;
int **p2;
int k;
```

We can then initialize `k` and make `p` point to it. Afterwards we can let `p2` *point to the pointer* `p`:

```
k = 10;
p = &i;
p2 = &p;
```

We will now dereference `p2` twice to see what the value *the pointer `p2` points to* are pointing at (using simple C++):

```
#include <iostream>
...
std::cout << "What is k? Answer: " << **p2;
```

*--> What is k? Answer: 10*

It is also possible to change the value of `k` by dereferencing it

```
**p2 = 19;
std::cout << "What is k now? Answer: " << **p2;
```

*--> What is k now? Answer: 19*

I hope this can help new programmers get an idea of how pointers to pointers can dereferenced. If triple (or more) pointers are wanted, simply dereference more levels

```
int ***p3 = &p2;
***p3 = 60;
std::cout << "What is k now? Answer: " << ***p3;
```

*--> What is k now? Answer: 60*

More information about what dereferencing really means can be found in

[What does "dereferencing" a pointer mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean)

Comment: Instead of "p = &i;", did you mean "p = &k;"?