# I'm receiving the error invalid "type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')" in my arduino code. What does it mean?

Tags: arduino

```
int vss=(pulseIn(vssp, HIGH)*(1/90))**(-1);  //This line works fine
while(vss<5){
  int vss=(pulseIn(vssp, HIGH)*(1/90))**(-1);   //This is where I get the error
}
```

I get the error "type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')" when I try to verify the code and have no idea what it means. This is my first time programming in anything other than python so the more information you have about what i'm doing wrong, the better.

Comment: `This line works fine` I don't think so what is the `**`? Is it double dereferencing?

Answer (score 0):

you are redeclaring the variable `vss` which has been already declared before the `while` loop.
Remove the `int` and should work.

Answer (score 0):

`**` In C is not the same as `**` in python. In C `*` could be used for multiplication or to [dereference pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean)

Maybe you want [`pow` function](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Pow), but be carefull with this cause it could give [wrong results](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=3056.0)

If you're just trying to trying to power to `-1` then you could just divide it

```
int vss = 1/(pulseIn(vssp, HIGH)*(1/90));
```

But this makes no sense, cause `int` can hold only integer values

And as they told you, you're redeclaring vss