# What does an arrow pointing upwards mean in pseudocode?

Tags: binary-search-tree, pseudocode, red-black-tree

I am encountering an *up-arrow* in pseudocode examples of balanced binary search trees. What is the author intending to denote by the use of such a symbol which can either follow or precede a variable?

```
type data = ....;
  Tree = ↑node;
  node = record
    left, right: Tree;
    level: integer;
    key: data;
  end;
var bottom, deleted, last: Tree;

procedure InitGlobalVariables;
begin
  new (bottom);
  bottom↑.level := 0;
  bottom↑.left := bottom;
  bottom↑.right := bottom;
  deleted := bottom;
end;
```

This pseudocode is a reference to building Red-Black-Trees found [here](http://user.it.uu.se/~arnea/ps/simp.pdf) written by Arne Andersson.

Answer (score 1):

The up-arrow is not a standard. In fact pseudo-code is not really a standard either so each author has some liberty in what notations they use.

The author should have made a legend for the pseudo-code explaining what the up-arrow means.

**My interpretation** is that it is intended to show that Tree is a pointer to a data structure of type node. The notation is somewhat reminiscent of Pascal.

And the up-arrow following a variable is intended to denote that the pointer variable is being [dereferenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean) .

Comment: Since the arrow is pointing up, it could refer to the parent of the current node

Comment: @jcpennypincher while possible, it's unlikely; more likely it's used to denote a pointer, and later to denote a pointer dereference

Comment: By that logic it could be anything you want it to be. It's psuedocode which means it doesn't have a defined syntax. Whoever wrote it should be more explicit and perhaps leave a comment. since we are talking about a balanced binary search tree I would assume it is the pointer to the parent node which is always above the child node, up above. I would bet $50 that is what the author meant.

Comment: @jcpennypincher I'm not a gambling man myself but I'll take you up on the $50 dollars - perhaps we can track down Arne Andersson, the author, and get some closure (no pun intended)