# Array Inside the Size of Another

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So I have a program that needs to increment the value in the first array, in whatever position is set by the second array.

i.e: A user enters the number 5 into an array. The program then goes to that position (5) in the second array and increments it's value by one. So far the code works fine, but I have to use Pointer notation and not Subscript, and am struggling with the correct syntax. Here's the code:

```
void enter_into_frequency(int *frequency_temp, int *user_numbers_temp)
{
     int i;
     for(i=0; i<NO_OF_NUMS; i++)
     {
          //Frequency array, with position as whatever number the user entered
          frequency_temp[user_numbers_temp[i]]++; //Need this in pointer notation
     }
}
```

Comment: It is always good to know that `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)` in pointer notation. (for 2D, `a[i][j]` is equivalent to `*(*(a + i) + j)`. Hope that helps.

Comment: That does! Thank you David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you need in pointer notation would be the following:

```
 ( *(frequency_temp + *(user_numbers_temp + i)) )++;
```

You can dereference a pointer using the `*`-operator and if you add an offset to your pointer you are able to dereference your array.

You can also have a look on this [What does “dereferencing” a pointer mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean)

Answer (score 2):

```
( *( frequency_temp + ( *(user_numbers_temp + i) ) ) )++;
```

This can be used in place of what you have right now.

```
/*  user_numbers_temp[i]  ->  *(user_numbers_temp+i)    */
/*  frequency_temp[user_numbers_temp[i]]  -> *(frequency_temp+(*(user_numbers_temp+i))) */
```

And then apply the `++` operator .