# What does &pointer gets?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am a noobie in C++ and its pointers, and I don't understand why in this code it is showing different addresses. I am also having trouble to understand if pointers can hold values or only addresses.

```
int* y;
std::cout << "y address is: " << y << std::endl;
std::cout << "y address is: " << &y << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
y address is: 0x41c33e
y address is: 0x28fefc
```

Comment: `&` gets the address of its operand. That's all you need to know (assuming you know what a pointer is.)

Comment: Before understanding pointers, you need to understand _type, object and value`. Example `int a = 7` defines the _object_ `a`, with _type_ `int`, and initial value `7`.

Answer (score 3):

The value of a pointer can be the address of a different object.
You get two different addresses printed because the pointer itself is also stored at some memory address:

```
int* y;    // y is pointing to some address (where there is not yet a int!)

std::cout << "y address is: " << y << std::endl;  // this is the adress 
                                                  // the pointer is pointing to
std::cout << "y address is: " << &y << std::endl; // this is the memory
                                                  // address where the
                                                  // pointer is stored
```

Answer (score 2):

What is a pointer?

Pointer is a variable that contains the address of another variable.

Here you take the address pointed to by the pointer:

```
std::cout << "y address is: " << y << std::endl;
```

As the pointer have his own address, here you take address of this pointer:

```
std::cout << "y address is: " << &y << std::endl;
```

That's why are two different addresses.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting confused with what pointers actually are.

```
int y;
int* y_pointer = &y;
```

In the above, `y` holds an integer, and `y_pointer` holds the memory address that `y` resides in (note the `&` meaning *address of*). Pointers can only hold memory addresses (as they are *pointers* to memory elements), but this doesn't mean you can't access the variable they point to.

Dereferencing pointers using the `*` character can be used to do this. 
There is a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean) about doing that for further reading.

Answer (score 1):

```
//to understand it better lets do
int x;
int* y=&x;
```

The type of the variable `y` is `int*` which is an integer pointer.

`y` gives the memory address value that is stored in the integer pointer, which would be the memory location where `x` is stored.

`&y` is the address of the variable `y` itself, i.e the memory location where the pointer is stored.