# Why doesn't my code swap the value of the variables even when I make use of pointers?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, swap

```
#include<stdio.h>
void mystery(int *ptra, int *ptrb) 
{
   int *temp;
   temp = ptrb;
   ptrb = ptra;
   ptra = temp;
}
int main() 
{
    int a=2016, b=0, c=4, d=42;
    mystery(&a, &b);
    if (a < c)
        mystery(&c, &a);
    mystery(&a, &d);
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

I am attempting to swap the value of the variables by making use of pointers but I fail to understand why the variables contain the same value even after the function calls

Comment: *temp -> temp and assign a return value to the non-void function .

Comment: This code is apparently from a book, judging by the large number of completely identical duplicates already present on SO. Please do some research before asking a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change *content* being pointed to by the pointers, not the pointers themselves.

```
void mystery(int *ptra, int *ptrb) 
{
   int temp; //make it non-pointer also.
   temp = *ptrb;
   *ptrb = *ptra;
   *ptra = temp;
}
```

If you change the pointer themselves, the change will be local to the function, because the variables `ptra` and `ptrb` are local variables, holding the addresses.

Remember, in general, that when you deal with a pointer, there is usually **two** objects involved:

- the pointer itself
- the object which the pointer points to, i.e the content.

In your case, you're dealing with the pointers *only*, not the contents — and the pointers themselves are *passed by value*, which is why the changes to pointer variables are local to the function.

Also, note that there is already `std::swap` which does the job. In case you're unaware of it, use it instead.

Comment: So, doesn't changing the address to which, the pointer points to, affect the value contained in them?

Comment: No since the address is passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `mystery` function, the notation you'd have needed to use to actually access the values to which the pointers point is:

```
*ptra
```

That's called *dereferencing* the pointer.  I have an old answer about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955297/410767).

So:

```
void mystery(int *ptra, int *ptrb) 
{
   int temp = *ptrb;
   *ptrb = *ptra;
   *ptra = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not swapping the values of the variable pointed by the pointer but you are swapping the addresses instead.

use * beside the pointer to use the value instead of address.