# c++ - What does ptr->ai_family do vs AF_INET

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, winsock2

I am going through msdn's "[Getting Started With Winsock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545(v=vs.85).aspx)" and they open a socket with the parameters

```
struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                *ptr    = NULL,
                hints;

iResult = getaddrinfo(
        argv[1], 
        DEFAULT_PORT, 
        &hints, 
        &result
);

ptr=result;

ConnectSocket = socket(
        ptr->ai_family,                 // Address Family (address families like ipv6 ipv4)
        ptr->ai_socktype,               // Type (Like tcp, udp ect)
        ptr->ai_protocol                // Protocol to use (0 = service provider chooses)
    );
```

But binarytides "[Winsock tutorial](http://www.binarytides.com/winsock-socket-programming-tutorial/)" does it like this (They are using C but I have seen people do this in c++)

```
s = socket(
    AF_INET , 
    SOCK_STREAM , 
    0 
)
```

What does ptr-> do?
and why use it over just setting it like AF_INET?

Also If you have free time and know sockets well I would appreciate some help.

Comment: You didn't show what `ptr` is so hard to say.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen aahhh yes, just edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
socket(ptr->ai_family,ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
```

passes in variables to create the socket, instead of hard coding the values. The advantage you get is that the code works for both IPv4 and IPv6.

`ptr->ai_family` is just an integer, a member of a [struct addrinfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). (And if you are wondering about the particular syntax of `ptr->`, you can go through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean) ), it will have a value of either `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6` (Or in theory any other supported protocol)

The call to `getaddrinfo()` will look up the host name, and resolve it to either an IPv4 or IPv6, and you pass in the result to socket() to create a socket of the proper type. If the hostname resolves to an IPv4 host, you create a socket that can deal with IPv4, If it resolves to IPv6, you create an IPv6 socket.

If you instead hard coded the values, e.g. as `AF_INET`, you would only support IPv4, whilst `ptr->ai_family` could be either `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6`.

Comment: Thank you! that is so understandably put! So far I haven't found one easy to understand tutorial on the subject of winsock XD.