# Need help in understanding left shift operator in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a few issues understanding the left shift operator. I know that if shifts by x amount of bits to the left, therefore pretty much multiplying the number to 2 to the power of the number of bits shifted.

But consider this program:

```
int a=4,*pA=&a,r3;
printf("%d\n",pA);
printf("%d\n",(*pA<<2));
r3=pA-(*pA<<2);
printf("%d",r3);
```

It prints out pA, and (*pA<<2) separately, and if you were to subtract these two, it won't equal to the r3 written in the expression, being off by 4 times, which is the size of int. But where do you need to take the size of int into consideration, since you have both pA and (*pA<<2), and their subtraction doesn't equal to what it's supposed to.

Any help is appreciated...

For the record, I am not interested in printing out the actual value of the pointer, but actually its address being shifted by 2 bits. And I don't understand the exact process that is happening.

Comment: What is it, what did you expect?

Comment: For a=4, pA comes up as 2686724, and *pA<<2 is 80.
But r3 comes up as 2686404, instead of 2686644.

Comment: `pA` is a pointer.. You're printing the address of the pointer. To print the actual value, you'd need to dereference it.

Comment: pA is an address (of a). Perhaps you meant to use *pA?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "dereferencing" a pointer mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean)

Comment: No, I don't want to use the value that pA is pointing at, I want to use the address.

Comment: arithmetic on a pointer scales with the size of what it points to. So when you do `pA - 80` your code actually does `pA - 80*sizeof(*pA)`. This has nothing to do with `<<`.

Comment: Instead of `r3=pA-(*pA<<2);` did you mean `r3=*pA-(*pA<<2);`?

Comment: Why is *pA<<2 = 80? It should be 16.

Comment: My bad, it's 32, considering sizeof(int)=4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arithmetic on a pointer scales with the size of what it points to. So when you do `pA - 80` your code actually does `pA - 80*sizeof(*pA)`. This has nothing to do with `<<`.

Also you should print addresses using the `%p` format specifier. And to store pointer values in an integer type use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` (from `stdint.h`). Enable warnings on your compiler and it should complain if you don't do this.

Comment: Makes the most sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The dereference operator `*` has higher precedence than the left-shift operator `<<`.  So the expression `*pA<<2` actually evaluates to `(*pA)<<2`.  This give you the value **pointed to** by `pA`, i.e. `a` left shifted by 2.

It seems like what you want is `pA<<2`, however a pointer is not a valid operand to the `<<` operator.  Multiplying a pointer value is not defined, nor does it makes sense.  You can however add to or subtract from a pointer.

The index operator `[]` is a syntactic sugar around adding to a pointer and dereferencing, so you could use that.  However, `pA` points to a single `int`, not an array, so doing so is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: No, I indeed want it to be shifted by (*pA)<<2.

Comment: @Radu That's what you're doing now, i.e. shifting the value not the pointer.  Shifting a pointer makes no sense.