# how to convert a long int to an int in C

Tags: c, int, long-integer

Mostly just the title, I want to know how I can put the random value which is a long int into an int variable address.

```
void SpinReel(int *a, int *b)
{
    long int reela = random() % 40;
    a= (int) reela;
    printf("&d\n", a);
    long int reelb = random() % 40;
    b= (int) reelb;
    printf("&d\n", b);

}
```

I am fairly new to C so I may just be misunderstanding the problem as well.

Comment: Just dereference `a` and `b`. You're 2 characters away from success.

Comment: Umm just put it into an int directly?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter a is not an int but a pointer to an int. To assign a value, you need to dereference the pointer.

```
*a = (int) reela;
```

[What dereferencing a pointer means](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4955198/101087)

Comment: `a*` - > `*a`..

Comment: @ForceBru thanks, corrected. Typing on tablet ;-)