# Buffer operations with shift and or operations

Tags: c

I'm not very sure of my code and want to improve it.

I receive some datas from SPI (8 bits communication) and store it into a buffer of 8 bits so. To use it, I want to use 32 bits word. I know my first code will work but I'm not sure about the second one, can anyone confirm it ?

```
uint8_t *regData[5];

spi_xfer(fd, "\x24\xFF\xFF\xFF\xCC", 5, regData, 5);
uint32_t regVal;
regVal = (regData[0]);
regVal += (uint32_t)(regData[1]) << 8; 
regVal += (uint32_t)(regData[2]) << 16; 
regVal += (uint32_t)(regData[3]) << 24;
```

The second one :

```
uint8_t *regData[5];

spi_xfer(fd, "\x24\xFF\xFF\xFF\xCC", 5, regData, 5);
uint32_t regVal;
regVal = (regData[0]) | (uint32_t)(regData[1]) << 8 | (uint32_t)(regData[2]) << 16 | (uint32_t)(regData[3]) << 24;
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Brieuc

Comment: For code that is already working, you might want to ask in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead. Aside from that, you should write tests to make sure code is working.

Comment: Side note: `uint8_t *regData[5];` looks wrong on both versions. It looks like you are serializing array of pointers. But it's unclear, as we don't know what `spi_xfer` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uint8_t *regData[5];
```

The `regData[]` is an array of pointers. If this is intended, to retrieve the value stored at the pointer in the array you need to [dereference the pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean).

```
regVal = *(regData[0]);
```

Otherwise the operation will assign the address stored at `regData[0]` to `regVal`, rather than the value stored at the address.

Comment: Is that not easier to use the code like this ?

 (uint8_t regData[5];

 spi_xfer(fd, "\x24\xFF\xFF\xFF\xCC", 5, regData, 5);
 uint32_t regVal;
 regVal = (regData[0]) | (uint32_t)(regData[1]) << 8 | (uint32_t)(regData[2]) << 16 | (uint32_t)(regData[3]) << 24;)

Thanks a lot for your answers !

Comment: The `or` operation is valid. I would suggest wrapping each condition in brackets, e.g. `((uint32_t)(regData[x]) << 8)`.