# C - Reference after dereference terminology

Tags: c, terminology, offsetof

This question is about terminology.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char array[10] = {0};

    void *ptr = array;

    void *middle = &ptr[5]; // <== dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
}
```

Gcc emits the warning *Dereferencing void pointer*.

I understand the warning because the compiler needs to compute the actual offset, and it couldn't because `void` has no standard size.

But I disagree with the error message. This is not a dereference. I can't find a dereference explanation where it is something else than taking value of something.

Same thing for offsetof:

```
#define offsetof(a,b) ((int)(&(((a*)(0))->b)))
```

There are lot of threads about whether this is UB because of a null pointer dereference. But this is not a null pointer dereference! Is it?

There is no *storage access* in the assembly code

```
mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-48]
add rax, 5
mov QWORD PTR [rbp-40], rax
```

What is the difference between dereference and storage access?

Comment: Formally in this expression  ptr[5] there is used dereferencing.

Comment: Array accesses are dereferences. You do a `ptr[5]` which derefences the 6th element of `ptr`. The fact that you then take a pointer to it doesn't alter the original dereference.

Comment: The expression `ptr[5]` is *defined* to be equivalent to the expression `*((ptr) + (5))`, in which the dereferencing is more clear.  That you don't actually attempt to access the storage has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Until now I considered the dereference as the storage access. Isn't it so ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean

Comment: The standard does not provide a formal definition of the term, @Bilow, so there's room for debate, but I would certainly claim that "dereferencing" is the effect of evaluating an expression using the unary `*` operator.  That's a prerequisite for, but not part of, accessing the storage.

Comment: "I considered the dereference as the storage access" --> dereference has at least 2 stages, the computation of the effective address and then the access.  Even though no access occurs here, the computation of the address is not specified and so UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I disagree with the error message. This is not a dereference. I can't find a dereference explanation where it is something else than taking value of something.

The standard does not provide a formal definition of the term "dereference".  The only place it uses it at all is in (non-normative) [footnote 102](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note102):

> [...] Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary `*` operator are a null pointer, an address inappropriately aligned for the type of object pointed to, and the address of an object after the end of its lifetime.

Note well, however, that this note characterizes dereferencing as the behavior of the unary `*` operator, not the effect of performing some other operation on the result.  You can think of the operation as converting a pointer into the object to which it points, which you will recognize presents an issue if the pointer does not, in fact, point to an object of the pointed-to type, or if the pointed-to type is an incomplete one such as `void`.  Such an issue exists formally even if the resulting object goes unused.

Now I acknowledge that there is room for confusion here on account of the fact that it is useless to perform a dereference without using the resulting object, but that's beside the point.  Consider the following complete C statement:

```
1 + 2;
```

Would you deny that it performs an addition just because the result is unused?

Now, your (sub-)expression `ptr[5]` is defined to have meaning identical to that of `(*((ptr)+(5)))`.  The type of a pointer addition expression is the same as the type of the pointer involved, so the that indeed does involved dereferencing a `void *`, in the sense of applying the unary `*` operator to an expression of that type.

Nevertheless, although I think the error message is correct, **I do agree that it is a poor choice**.  A more fundamental problem here, and one that is reached first in evaluation order, is a violation of the language constraint that in pointer addition, the pointer must point to a *complete* type, which `void` is not.  Indeed, it's hard to construe the message that is emitted as satisfying the requirement that constraint violations result in a diagnostic.  It seems to be about a different problem -- one that produces undefined behavior, but does not involve a constraint violation.

You also remark:

> Same thing for offsetof:
>
> ```
> #define offsetof(a,b) ((int)(&(((a*)(0))->b)))
> ```
>
> [...] But this is not a null pointer dereference! Is it?

Be careful, there.  The C language does not define the specific form of the replacement text of the `offsetof()` macro; what you've presented is an implementation detail.

We could easily divert into semantics here, since "dereference" is not a defined term in the standard, so I'll address instead a similar question: *when the macro arguments meet the requirements of the `offsetof()` macro, does the definition presented expand to an expression with well-defined behavior?*

The standard does not define behavior for the indirect member selection operator (`->`) when its left-hand operand has an acceptable type but does not point to any object (such as when it is null).  The behavior is therefore undefined.  Or if we take `a->b` to be wholly equivalent to `((*a).b)`, then the behavior is explicitly undefined when `a` does not point to any object.  Either way, the C language does not define behavior for the expression.

But this is where it becomes important that your particular macro definition is an implementation detail.  The implementation from which it is drawn is free to provide whatever behavior it wishes, and in particular, it can provide behavior that reliably satisfies C's specifications for the `offsetof()` macro.  You should not rely on such code yourself.  Even on an implementation that provides an `offsetof()` definition of that form, you cannot be certain that it does not also employ some special internal magic -- not available directly to your own code -- to make it work.

Comment: `1 + 2;` could be executed even with its result unused. But if you try to take the address of that rvalue, if won't even compile at all. If `ptr[5]` was actually executed, wouldn't it fail to compile if you take its address, you see what I mean ?

Comment: @Bilow, the point of the analogy is that just as `1 + 2` constitutes an addition, regardless of whether or how the result is used, `*p` constitutes a dereference of  pointer `p`, regardless of whether or how the result is used.  The expression `ptr[5]` is defined to have meaning identical to the expression `(*((ptr) + (5)))`, so it indeed does constitute a dereference, contrary to your claim "This is not a dereference".  Inasmuch as the expression has undefined behavior both with and without an `&` operator, there's not really any place else to go with that.