# Why dereference a reference in C? Using & next to *

Tags: c, pointers, scanf, pass-by-reference, ampersand

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094666/pointers-in-c-when-to-use-the-ampersand-and-the-asterisk) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931850/why-doesnt-scanf-need-an-ampersand-for-strings-and-also-works-fine-in-printf-i) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406935/reading-a-string-with-scanf) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47081879/c-reference-after-dereference-terminology) and more.

**Question is**:

A basic C Programming MOOC on EdX is showing how to access a member of a struct within a function, when the struct was passed by pointer. **Why in the world are they using `&` next to `*`???**

They show: `scanf("%lf", &(*studptr).aveGrade);`

Why not just use `studptr.aveGrade` in scanf?

(*Leaving aside the separate question, "why use scanf at all"*)

(Was asked for complete example)

```
void readStudent(struct student *studptr) {
    print("\nEnter a new student record: \n");
    printf("First name: ");
    scanf("%s", (*studptr).firstName);
    printf("Last name: ");
    scanf("%s", (*studptr).lastName);
    printf("Birth year: ");
    scanf("%d", &(*studptr).birthYear);
    printf("Average grade: ");
    scanf("%lf", &(*studptr).aveGrade);
}
```

Comment: Is it intented, that the first two `scanf()` do not have the `&`?

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica — yes, the inputs are strings so the `&` is not required.  (More precisely, though less concisely, the members `firstname` and `lastname` are almost certainly arrays of `char` and therefore passing them as written passes a `char *` which is what `%s` expects.  Adding the `&` would pass a `char (*)[n]` where `n` is the size of the array — a very different type.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you very much, Jonathan. I did not knew the case when you have the input assignment of `scanf`()` to a stucture´s member. So, this coding technique is equivalent to `scanf("%s",array);` when `a` would be an array of `char`, and `&` is redundant, if not invalid though, because `array` already points to the first element of the array, which is required for the operation.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica — yes, the situations are essentially the same. Using the `&` is technically incorrect (as I said) because the type of pointer passed in is incorrect.  In practice, you normally get away with it, but it is officially UB (undefined behaviour) and UB should be avoided at all costs (and typing one less character is a very small cost).

Comment: it is not next, as there's a parenthesis in between.  Check operator precedence and you'll see that `.` has higher precedence than `&`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `&` doesn't refer to `(*stupdtr)`, it refers to `(*studptr).aveGrade`. The `.` operator has higher precedence.

Comment: So many good answers! But this was first and most concise answer, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 8):

In the fragment:

```
scanf("%lf", &(*studptr).aveGrade);
```

the `&` operator applies as if there were parentheses:

```
scanf("%lf", &((*studptr).aveGrade));
```

There's no good reason to use `(*ptr).member` in preference to `ptr->member`; indeed, explicit indirection notation is more verbose, and doubly so when there are chains of operations:

```
(*(*(*ptr).ptrmember).altptr).member
```

vs:

```
ptr->ptrmember->altptr->member
```

So, the code should be:

```
scanf("%lf", &studptr->aveGrade);
```

Yes, the two are 'equivalent', but the arrow notation is idiomatic C and the other is not.

Comment: Thanks, I could tell this MOOC was outdated and/or pedantic

Answer (score 3):

The two symbols are referring to different things.

The `&` is taking the address of the `aveGrade` member.

The `*` is deferencing the `studptr` to get a structure.

---

If it were up to me, I'd write it using the Arrow operator for pointers-to-structures:

```
scanf("%lf", &studptr->aveGrade);
```

If you want parens to clarify:

```
scanf("%lf", &(studptr->aveGrade) );
```

Comment: The 'parentheses to clarify' might be of use to a novice programmer, but using them emphasises "novice".  I couldn't recommend them.  YMMV — and apparently does.

Answer (score 3):

> Why not just use studptr.aveGrade in scanf?

As you wrote `studptr` is a pointer, So this expression `studptr.aveGrade` is invalid.

It is correctly to write either `studptr->aveGrade` or `( *studptr ).aveGrade`

So the call of scanf can be written either like

```
scanf("%lf", &studptr->aveGrade);
```

or like

```
scanf("%lf", &(*studptr).aveGrade);
```

Take into account that

```
&(*studptr).aveGrade
```

and

```
( &*studptr).aveGrade
```

are different expressions.

The first expression can be rewritten using more parentheses like

```
& ( ( *studptr ).aveGrade )
```

Answer (score 1):

It's true that when `&` immediately precedes `*` that the two cancel each other out.  However, that's not what's happening here:

```
&(*studptr).aveGrade
```

Looking at each operator:

- The `*` operator is applied to `studptr` in the parenthesized expression
- Given `(*studptr)`, the `.` operator has higher precedence than `&` so it is applied next
- `&` is then applied to (*studptr).aveGrade)

So `&` is giving you the address of the `aveGrade` member of what `studptr` points to.  Without parenthesis, the `&` and `*` would cancel and you'd get a syntax error because  `studptr` is a pointer to a struct, not a struct.

Answer (score 0):

In structure, `aveGrade` is `double` so if you want to access that you need to dereference `studptr` to `aveGrade` by using ampersand(&). So it's absurd to use `(*studptr).aveGrade` in `scanf`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think if you read the other answers you'll see why the construct is not absurd -- just outdated. @Johnathon Leffler's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59396315/3255525 explains why -> is better, more accepted practice.

Comment: @JimLohse yes I know about arrow operator being preferred over this way. They about arrow operator should be preferred in mooc too.