# c++ segmentation fault after creating a point of a class

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a c++ code segment that throws segmentation **Error:**

Matrix representation of graph

0100

0010

1011

0000

Node, label:1,column index:0

/C/Program Files/NetBeans 8.1/ide/bin/nativeexecution/dorun.sh: line 33: 13140 **Segmentation fault**      sh "${SHFILE}"

**code snippet:**

```
     void graph::shortest_path(std::vector<std::vector<int>> &_matrix) {
    //1) initialize not visited nodes 
    int num_of_nodes = _matrix.size();
    std::queue<Node> unvisited;
    std::queue<Node> visited;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_nodes; i++) {
        unvisited.push(Node(i + 1));
    }



    //while unvisited is NOT empty
    while (!unvisited.empty()) {


        //2) pop/remove from unvisited & are there adjacent neighbors 
        Node node = unvisited.front();
        std::cout << "Node, label:" << node.getLabel() << ",column index:" << node.getLabel() - 1 << endl;
        vector<int>& columnVector = _matrix[node.getLabel() - 1];
        //nodes integer label 
        int label = 0;
        //loop add adjacency list * back pointers
        for (int c = 0; c < columnVector.size(); c++) {
            //if there are actual connections, then adjacency matrix value at C NOT equal INT_MAX
            if (columnVector[c] != INT_MAX) {
                //create a node & add to current nodes adjacency list 
                Node * adj = new Node(c+1); 
                adj->setPrev(node);
                node.addToAdjacenyList(*adj);
                //also set the prev reference 

            }
        }//end loop add adjacency list * back pointers


        //3) for each node calculate the total weight or cost back to the start & select the min 
        for (int i = 0; i < node.getAdjacenyList()->size(); i++) {
            cout << node.getAdjacenyList()->at(i).getLabel() << ",";


        }
        cout << endl;

        //keep track of visited nodes 
        visited.push(node);
        //since this node was visited remove/pop it from unvisited 
        unvisited.pop();


    }

}
```

However when I just instantiate without the new keyword I dont get any segmentation fault:

```
//loop add adjacency list * back pointers
        for (int c =0; c<columnVector.size(); c++)
        {
            //if there are actual connections, then adjacency matrix value at C NOT equal INT_MAX
            if (columnVector[c]!=INT_MAX)
            {
                //create a node & add to current nodes adjacency list 
                //Node * adj = new Node(c+1); 
                //adj->setPrev(node);
                node.addToAdjacenyList(Node(c+1));
                //also set the prev reference 

            }
        }//end loop add adjacency list * back pointers
```

**Ok Output:**

Matrix representation of graph

0100

0010

1011

0000

Node, label:1,column index:0
2,
Node, label:2,column index:1
3,
Node, label:3,column index:2
1,3,4,
Node, label:4,column index:3

```
**Here is the Node class:**

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

#include "Node.h"
#include <vector>

Node::Node()
{

}

Node::Node(int label):_label(label)
{

}

Node::~Node()
{
    Node::_adjacency_list->clear(); 
}

void Node::setLabel(int val)
{
    _label = val; 
}

int Node::getLabel()
{
    return _label; 
}

void Node::setWeight(int val)
{
    _weight = val; 
}

int Node::getWeight()
{
    return _weight; 
}

int Node::getDistance()
{
    return _distance;
}

void Node::setDistance(int val)
{
    _distance = val; 
}

/*
 * std::vector<Node>* getAdjacenyList();
    void addToAdjacenyList(const Node& node);
 */

std::vector<Node>* Node::getAdjacenyList()
{
    std::vector<Node>* point = &*_adjacency_list;
    return point; 
}

void Node::addToAdjacenyList(const Node& node)
{
    _adjacency_list->push_back(node);
/*
 * 
 *  Node* getPrev();
    void  setPrev(const Node& node); 
 */
}

Node* Node::getPrev()
{
     Node* point = &*_prev;
     return point; 
}

void Node::setPrev(const Node& n)
{
    *_prev = n; 
}
```

Why am I getting segmentation fault & how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `{ Node * adj = new Node(c+1); adj->setPrev(node);   node.addToAdjacenyList(*adj); }` -- Memory leak.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, why is that a memory leak. Pointer of type Node is instantiated using new Node(c+1). Then its accessed. Please elaborate.

Comment: How are you going to `delete` that Node pointer when that pointer goes out of scope?   Do you save that pointer value somewhere for later `delete`-tion?

Comment: @Im not finished coding ,inside the ~Node destructor, I will iterate through the Nodes adjacency list and call delete. Actually in the ~Node() im calling adjacency_list->clear();

Comment: @cyber101 -- You have a clear misunderstanding of what `new` does in `C++`.  C++ is not Java.  What pointers are you saving?  This: `node.addToAdjacenyList(*adj);` does not use or save any pointers.

Comment: @cyber101 -- It is very simple.  The `new` in C++ returns a pointer value to you.  You must save this value so that later on, you can call `delete`.  You declared a *local* `adj` pointer.  It got assigned a value by `new`.  You then go out-of-scope, losing the pointer and the value it was assigned.  Memory leak.  What you probably are being confused by is `*adj` -- That is *not* a pointer -- it is an object.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 1) When new is used to allocate memory for a C++ class object, the object's constructor is called after the memory is allocated. That what I understand. 2) Yes C++ is NOT Java and Java is NOT C++, so what. 3) node.addToAdjacenyList(*adj) is NOT saving a pointer this dereferencing a pointer which passes pointer address to Node& node reference variable. Again how can I fix the code?

Comment: The fix: No `new`. `Node adj(c+1);` allocates and constructs an Automatic variable. It's copied into `_adjacency_list` by `push_back`, and the original goes out of scope and destructs. From there `_adjacency_list` manages all of the storage for you.

Comment: A note about `Node::_adjacency_list->clear();`: `vector` automatically clears for you on destruction so you don't need to do this (See [The Rule of Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)) and you shouldn't need to prefix with the class name. If you get an error if you don't use the classname, likely you have another bug lurking somewhere.

Comment: @cyber101 -- So you finally admit it is a memory leak?  The reason why I mention Java is that code that has `new` all over the place without a single `delete` is a tell-tale sign of Java-like coding going on in a C++ program.  Second, you get less issues with code that reduces or eliminates the usage of pointers.  Segmentation faults are an indication of pointer mismanagement.

Comment: An unrelated note on using underscore prefixes: Underscores often mean something in C++. Use them with caution. More on the subject here: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Answer (score 1):

```
void Node::setPrev(const Node& n)
{
    *_prev = n; 
}
```

`_prev` is never pointed at a valid memory location before [dereferencing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean) and copying `n` into it. Dereferencing an invalid pointer invokes dreaded [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Copying into invalid memory is also Undefined Behaviour and is likely what's resulting in the Segmentation fault.

Probably what you need intend is

```
void Node::setPrev(Node * n)
{
    _prev = n; 
}
```

But this will likely set off a potentially nasty chain of events elsewhere because the adjacency list is also storing copies. A significant redesign is in order.

There is an immediate echo in

```
Node* Node::getPrev()
{
     Node* point = &*_prev;
     return point; 
}
```

`&*_prev;` dereferences the pointer and promptly takes the address again. Net result is doing nothing useful if `_prev` is pointing at valid memory. If `_prev` is not pointing at valid memory, and it isn't, the result of `*_prev` is undefined.

```
Node* Node::getPrev()
{
     return _prev; 
}
```

is safer, but places the onus on the receiver to make sure what it received is valid before attempting to use it.