# Modification of dereferenced value leads to modification of true value

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

I have some code taken as examples to pointer.

```
short value=7;

short *ptr=&value;

std::cout<<&value<<'\n';
std::cout<<value<<'\n';
std::cout<<ptr<<'\n';
std::cout<<*ptr<<'\n';
std::cout<<'\n';

*ptr=9;

std::cout<<&value<<'\n';
std::cout<<value<<'\n';
std::cout<<ptr<<'\n';
std::cout<<*ptr<<'\n';
std::cout<<'\n';
```

I wonder when I change *ptr to 9, why does the value of "value" change according to *ptr?

Comment: This is how pointers work.  When you dereference them you have the object the pointer points to.  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "dereferencing" a pointer mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean)

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder when I change *ptr to 9, why does the value of "value" change according to *ptr?

Because `ptr` points to `value`. The result of the indirection operation is an l-value that designates the pointed object.