# C++: Why do i not need to dereference for initialising dynamic arrays?

Tags: c++

Given the code below:

```
double** vr(new double*[nx]);  
vr[i]=new double[ny];
for(int i=0;i<nx;++i) { //Loop 200times
    for(int j=0;j<ny;++j) { //Loop 200times

        vr[i][j]=double(i*i*i*j*c1);

    }
}
```

For `vr[i][j] = double(i * i * i * j * c1);`

why is it not required to address the value using `*` for example `*(vr[i][j])`.

It is just an address isnt it?

Comment: This is pretty much answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean/4955297#4955297). Array indexing and pointer arithmetic are the same idea expressed in different syntax.

Comment: and your question is not initialization but assignment.

Comment: I just wanted to ask why does it dereference? 
Is there some kind of overloaded [] operator for a pointer class maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Subscript operator (`[i]`) does the dereferencing. It says to shift on `i` "cells" and get the object located there.

Comment: I just wanted to ask why does it dereference? 
Is there some kind of overloaded [] operator for a pointer class maybe?

Comment: @cLMaine It is the semantics. Why does `+` summarize? You used c-style pointers. They are not classes. But, for example, `unique_ptr` has overloaded [] operator.

Answer (score 1):

From [dcl.array/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.meaning#dcl.array-6)

> the subscript `operator []` is interpreted in such a way that `E1[E2]`
>   is identical to `*((E1)+(E2))` ([expr.sub]). Because of the conversion
>   rules that apply to `+`, if `E1` is an array and `E2` an integer, then
>   `E1[E2]` refers to the `E2-th` member of `E1`. Therefore, despite its
>   asymmetric appearance, subscripting is a *commutative operation*.
>    — end note ]

Thus, `operator[]`, the subscript operator, works the same as using `operator*` (unary) for indirection.

```
int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // array
int* pa = a;                // pointer to a
std::cout <<  pa[2];        // (ans. 3) using subscript operator
std::cout << *(pa + 2);     // (ans. 3) using indirection, accessing A's 3rd element
```

Comment: Do you think @NuPagadi should take notes?
Thanks btw! :)

Answer (score 1):

`vr[i][j]` is a `double` not an address.

Basically, if `p` is of type `T*` then `p[i]` means `*(p+i)` and is of type `T`, where `T` can be any type.

In your case `vr` is `double**`, so `vr[i]` is `double*` and `vr[i][j]` is `double`.

Comment: I just wanted to ask why does it dereference?

Comment: Is there some kind of overloaded [] operator for a pointer class maybe?

Answer (score 1):

When you do `vr[i]` you're already dereferencing because `vr[i]` is equivalent to `*(vr + i)`. This means that `vr[i][j]` is double dereferencing, and is equivalent to `*(*(vr + i) + j)`.

See [pointer arithmetic](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointer_arithmatic.htm) for further information.

Comment: I just wanted to ask why does it dereference? 
Is there some kind of overloaded [] operator for a pointer class maybe?