# Why can't I use std::begin/std::end with int(*p)[3] while I can with int(&p)[3]?

Tags: c++

This works:

```
void foo(int (&a)[3]) {
    auto ibegin = begin(a);
    auto ebegin = end(a);
}
```

While this doesn't:

```
void foo(int (*a)[3]) {
    auto ibegin = begin(a);
    auto ebegin = end(a);
}
```

I consider `int (&a)[3]` and `int (*a)[3]` have the same meaning!

Comment: A pointer is not an array. Those two declarations do not have the same meaning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is analogous to:

```
void foo(vector<int>& a) {
    auto ibegin = begin(a);
    auto ebegin = end(a);
}

void foo(vector<int>* a) {
    auto ibegin = begin(a);
    auto ebegin = end(a);
}
```

The first one works and the second one doesn't for the same reason as it works on `int (&a)[3]` and doesn't on `int (*a)[3]`. When you're using pointers to collections instead of references, you need to dereference them when you pass them to the standard library's `begin`/`end`.

```
void foo(vector<int>* a) {
    auto ibegin = begin(*a);
    auto ebegin = end(*a);
}

void foo(int (*a)[3]) {
    auto ibegin = begin(*a);
    auto ebegin = end(*a);
}
```

Comment: (@thedeg123, see other examples of ["analogous to"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/analogous). I'm fairly confident that it should be "to" and not "too".)

Comment: Thanks! All the answers explain well but your example is inspiring to me. I don't know that I can still use std::begin/std::end after dereferencing the pointer to array.

Comment: Yes, it works because dereferencing gets you a reference: for `int (*a)[3]`, `*a` has the type `int (&)[3]`, and it refers to the same object.

Comment: Apologies @zneak my mistake.

Answer (score 7):

> I consider `int (&a)[3]` and `int (*a)[3]` have the same meaning!

Absolutely not. `int (&a)[3]` declares a reference to array, and `int (*a)[3]` declares a pointer to array.  These are different in most of the same ways a reference to `int` and a pointer to `int` are different.  (Though when C-style arrays are involved, the automatic array-to-pointer conversion sometimes complicates things.)

Answer (score 4):

> I consider int (&a)[3] and int (*a)[3] have the same meaning!

No! The first one is a reference to an array, the second is a pointer to an array.

In C++14 `std::begin` and `std::end` are defined as:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N> 
constexpr T* begin(T (&array)[N]) noexcept;

template<class T, std::size_t N> 
constexpr T* end(T (&array)[N]) noexcept;
```

Clearly, the functions take a reference to an array, not a pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Btw, since I don't have to pass a size of a array while using reference（inside the function I can still use begin and end), so reference parameter for an array is practically better and used than pointer parameter for an array in all circumstances?

Comment: @Rick Yes, the pointer+size function parameters are discouraged in C++. Better yet, there's `std::array<int, 3>`.

Answer (score 4):

You may understand the difference in function overloading where the three are respectively reference to array, pointer to array and array of pointers. So they don't have the same meaning.

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int (&a)[3]) {
    std::cout << "(&a)[3]" << std::endl;
}

void foo(int (*a)[3]) { 
    std::cout << "(*a)[3]" << std::endl;
}

void foo(int *a[3]) {
    std::cout << "*a[3]" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int m[3];
    int *n[3] = {m + 0, m + 1, m + 2};
    foo(m);       // (&a)[3]
    foo(&m);      // (*a)[3]
    foo(n);       // *a[3]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `&` symbol is getting the location of the pointer in (&a) you are getting the address of `a` at location 0 in the array.

While `*a` is getting the value stored at a[0] this is called **dereferencing a pointer**. For example:

```
int * a = {0,1,2};

&a[0] //gets value of the memory pointer of a[0], maybe 0xff123
*a[0] //dereferences the pointer at [0] in this gets case '0'.
```

For a more complete look at pointers, I'd check out: [What does "dereferencing" a pointer mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean)