# How to dereference a pointer to a map of pointers to objects in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

In the example below, I want to access the `employeeID` from class `Employee` by using the pointer employeePayroll:

```
class Employee { ... int employeeID; ... }
std::map<std::string, Employee *> *_employeePayroll;
std::map<std::string, Employee *> _employeeID;
_employeePayroll = &_employeeID;
```

How can I access employeeID with a given key, e.g. to print the content?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "dereferencing" a pointer mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean)

Comment: I think you have some compile errors there.

Comment: Were you intending on finding a specific employee to gather their id? There is no `employeeID` member of `std::map<std::string, Employee *>`, so `employeePayroll->employeeID` is nonsense. And `static_cast<void*>_employeeID` is equally nonsense. Iit is missing the parens, and even if they were there, `employeeID` isn't a pointer-type, so static casting to `void*` is still nonsense. Remove the "quick" from your "quick question", formulate *exactly* what you're trying to do, the conditions you're trying to do it with, the inputs, the expected outputs, etc, and update your post.

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig, i changed it. Some typo errors and explain again.

Comment: what you really want? do you get error or something?

Comment: Something like `(*_employeePayroll)["name"]->employeeID` I guess is what you want, although it's hard to really know.

Comment: What I am getting is the memory address if I do cout << &_employeeID; instead of the variable value.  But Jonathan Potter is giving me the right idea now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
... (*_employeePayroll)["Karl"]->employeeID ...
```

NOTE: This works, but is dangerous! It will crash the programm as soon as the key "Karl" doesn't exist. Please, find the last code example below.

---

---

The safe way, using *find* and an *iterator*:

```
...
itEmployeeID = _employeePayroll->find("Karl");
if ( itEmployeeID != _employeePayroll->end() )
{
    ... (itEmployeeID->second)->employeeID ...
```

The complete test code is here:

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <string>
#include    <map>

class Employee
{
public:
    int     employeeID;

    Employee()
    {
        employeeID = 123;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::map<std::string, Employee *>                   *_employeePayroll;
    std::map<std::string, Employee *>                   _employeeID;
    std::map<std::string, Employee *>::const_iterator   itEmployeeID;

    _employeePayroll = &_employeeID;
    (*_employeePayroll)["Karl"] = new Employee;

    itEmployeeID = _employeePayroll->find("Karl");
    if ( itEmployeeID != _employeePayroll->end() )
    {
        std::cout << (itEmployeeID->second)->employeeID;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: The allocated memory has to be cleand up.

---

---

The complete test code of the "dangerous" variant is:

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <string>
#include    <map>

class Employee
{
public:
    int     employeeID;

    Employee()
    {
        employeeID = 123;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::map<std::string, Employee *> *_employeePayroll;
    std::map<std::string, Employee *> _employeeID;
    _employeePayroll = &_employeeID;

    int iValue;

    (*_employeePayroll)["Karl"] = new Employee;
    iValue = (*_employeePayroll)["Karl"]->employeeID;
    std::cout << iValue;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: The allocated memory has to be cleand up.

Comment: Thank you Jorg!!! This coding explanation helps a lot.  I will play around more with safe way.