# Assigning a unsigned char* a number

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm using an unsigned char* to store information that is going to be max around 200,
I am using a char pointer because a want to remove later like

```
unsigned char* hello = new unsigned char;
delete hello;
```

but when I try to assign it a value like `hello = 54` it gives the error
`a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "unsigned char*"`

Comment: `*hello = 54` Also, you can use `int8_t`

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: *I am using a char pointer because a want to remove later* -- Where did you learn this erroneous piece of information from?  That is not the reason to use pointers.

Comment: What does "remove later" mean?

Answer (score 2):

Do yourself a favor and just use `int` if it's an integer. Otherwise it gets messy once you come across function overloads that expect `char` objects to actually be characters (e.g., formatted stream IO):

```
int hello = 52;
```

If you really need to save some memory, you can use `unsigned char` directly:

```
unsigned char hello = 52;
```

If, for whatever reasons, you want to limit the lifetime of the object to a smaller scope, you can just introduce another level of nesting:

```
{
    unsigned char hello = 52;
} // no need to delete here, because the object is destroyed automatically
```

Note that you actually use *more* memory, when you declare a pointer (that is likely to be 64-bits wide nowadays) and dynamically allocate memory to hold a byte elsewhere.

If you really want to extend your object's lifetime beyond the current scope, you could use a smart pointer instead, to prevent issues like leaking memory or double free.

```
std::unique_ptr<char> hello = std::make_unique<char>(52);
```

But do note that this is usually a hassle and most often not necessary at all, especially for objects this small. Just declare a local variable, copy it around as needed, and be done with it.

---

Besides that, you need to [dereference the pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4955198/1025391) to access the object the pointer points to:

```
unsigned char * p = new unsigned char;
*p = 52;
delete p;
```