# How does the swap function work (pointer is used)?

Tags: c, function, pointers, swap

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b);

int main(void)
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;

    printf("x is %i, y is %i\n", x, y);
    swap(&x, &y);
    printf("x is %i, y is %i\n", x, y);
}

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

In this code (I didn't write it btw) **I don't understand how x and y are being swapped** when we are actually swapping `a` and `b`  in the function below. i do not know what the relationship between 'x and y' and 'a and b' is.

I know that `*` is a pointer, and that '&' gives the address to things, *but idk how it's pointing to `x` and `y` when they're ( `x` and `y`) not mentioned in the actual function.*

i don't know what 'placeholder' is being used.

Please explain this if you can!

Comment: Re "*nut idk how it's pointing to x and y*", You effectively did `a = &x; b = &y;` by calling the sub using `swap(&x, &y)`. You literally made `a` point to `x` and `b` point to `y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `a` and `b` are pointers and you actually pass the addresses of `x` and `y` in `main()` as arguments to the function `swap()` by *reference*:

```
swap(&x, &y);
```

If you use the `&` operator it gains the address of an object.

The parameter `a` gets assigned by the address of `x` and the parameter `b` gets assigned by the address of `y`.

If you dereference the pointers `a` and `b` properly and have a correct algorithm (as it is in this case), you interchange the values of `x` and `y` inside of `main()` and not the values of the pointers `a` and `b`.

To speak about the algorithm itself:

```
int tmp = *a;
*a = *b;
*b = tmp;
```

1. `int tmp = *a;` - The value of `x` is assigned to a temporary object. This is needed since we change the value of `x` at the next step.
2. `*a = *b;` - The value of `y` is assigned to `x`.
3. `*b = tmp;` - The value which was stored previously in `x` and was stored as place between in `tmp` (a temporary object) is now assigned to `y`.

Note that at all of these steps, the `*` operator doesn't mean to declare a pointer twice. It is used to *dereference* the pointer.

For more information about "dereferencing", take a look at:

[What does "dereferencing" a pointer mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean)

---

If the values of `x` and `y` have been passed by *value* (without the `&`) and the parameters `a` and `b` were just of type `int`, not `int *` then you would only change `a` and `b` inside of `swap()`.

---

I recommend you to learn more about pointers. For example in a free copy of [Modern C](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) made by community member [@JensGustedt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366377/jens-gustedt).

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the address of x and y to swap function. The parameters of this  function point to new address and swap the content of two address as the function does.