# value_comp and * before a iterator

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, iterator, stdmap

What does the `value_comp` do, like does it check the first value equal to the second?

and `*` operator before the iterator?

```
map<char, char> m = 
{
   { 'a', 'A' },
   { 'b', 'B' },
   { 'c', 'C' },
   { 'd', 'D' },
   { 'e', 'E' },
};

auto last = *m.rbegin(); // How does "*" affect the iterator returned
auto i = m.begin();

do 
{

   cout << i->first
      << " = "
      << i->second
      << endl;
} while (m.value_comp()(*i++, last));  
// Does the value_comp compares *i++ and the last value or iterator
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)? Could you explain your question more clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does "`*`" affect the iterator returned?

It [dereferences the iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean/4955297) and gives the pointee. Meaning the `last` has type

```
std::pair<const char, char>
```

or

```
decltype(m)::value_type // or std::map<char, char>::value_type
```

If you would have just `auto last = m.rbegin();` (i.e. without dereferencing), you would get the iterator there, meaning the `last` would have deduced to `std::map<char, char>::iterator`.

---

> Does the `value_comp` compares `*i++` and the `last value` or *iterator*?

[`std::map::value_comp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/value_comp) returns:

> a **function object** that compares objects of type
> `std::map::value_type` (key-value pairs) by using *key_comp* to
> compare the first components of the pairs.

Therefore, it compares the values of the map, not the iterator pointing to the key-value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

So, it looks like you have basically two questions:

> auto last = *m.rbegin(); //How does "*" affect the iterator returned

The "*" operator returns the reference of `value_type` which for your map would be `std::pair<const char, char>`.

> Does the value_comp compares *i++ and the last value or iterator

`value_comp()` returns the function that compares keys in objects of type value_type. So, in your code it compares keys `i->first` and `last.first`. It returns true if the first key is less

Answer (score 1):

> How does `"*"` affect the iterator returned?

The dereference (`*`) means that ***the value stored in `last` is not the iterator***, but a copy of what's stored at that position in the map, which incidentally is the last node of the map. It works much in the same way as dereferencing a pointer, you get the value pointed by it, not the pointer itself.

> Does the value_comp compares `*i++` and the last value or iterator?

Yes it does. It compares the two keys, the one "pointed by" `i` and the one stored in `last`. The method will return true as long as the first argument key is at a lower position on the map than the key of the second argument.

In your example, when the keys match the cycle ends.

As per the description of the method:

> ***It returns a comparison object that can be used to compare two elements to get whether the key of the first one goes before the second**.*
>
> *The comparison object returned is an object of the member type `map::value_compare`, which is a nested class that uses the internal comparison object to generate the appropriate comparison functional class.*

Side note:

It may be clear that `*i++` also returns the content of `i`, and the  iterator `i` is being incremented at each iteration, but this expression can cause confusion, you could use brackets to avoid it, like so `*(i++)`.