# C++ cast with additional round brackets

Tags: c++, function-pointers, implicit-conversion, function-call

What does the following statement do in C++?

```
(*JImageGetResource)(jimage, location, val, size);
```

This instruction is taken from [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/158e145e3a42/src/hotspot/share/classfile/classLoader.cpp#l1479).

Comment: It's not a cast; `JImageGetResource` is a variable, and it's a function pointer. (Search for it on that page.)

Comment: How is `JImageGetResource` defined? Without the definition you'll get plausible guesses that may or may not be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no cast involved. `JImageGetResource` is a pointer, by adding `*` in front of it, it will be [dereferenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean).
Typically you will see this with iterators for example.

In your case it's a function pointer. So the resulting code would be the same as `resultingFunction(jimage, location, val, size)`.

In line 1017: `JImageGetResource = CAST_TO_FN_PTR(JImageGetResource_t, dll_lookup(handle, "JIMAGE_GetResource", path));`

Answer (score 1):

No, that is no cast, because the thing in the left bracket is no type. It is an usual function call.

The left bracket dereference the pointer `JImageGetResource`, and the obtained object is something that can be called with 4 arguments.

Comment: Without context, `JImageGetResource` is not necessarily a pointer. It can also be of a class type with overloaded unary operator `*`. And the result is not necessarily an object; it can also be a function.

Comment: I partly second eerorika, from the code included in the question one cannot know what it is. Perhaps you are right, but you should at least refer to what is missing in the question that made you come to the conclusion

Comment: @eerorika Your right, it could be that it is no pointer, but it is initialized with NULL, so it is at least pointer like.

Comment: @eerorika An function pointer is an object too, isn't it?

Comment: @gerum Yes. Pointers are objects.

Answer (score 1):

Taking this declaration into account

```
static JImageGetResource_t             JImageGetResource      = NULL;
```

it means that the name `JImageGetResource` identifies a pointer of the type `JImageGetResource_t` that is initialized by `NULL`.

Also this record

```
 JImageGetResource = CAST_TO_FN_PTR(JImageGetResource_t, dll_lookup(handle, "JIMAGE_GetResource", path));
```

is self-documented and means `JImageGetResource` denotes a function pointer.

So this expression statement

```
(*JImageGetResource)(jimage, location, val, size);
```

represents a function call with four arguments.

This record could be written also like

```
JImageGetResource(jimage, location, val, size);
```

or to make a more obfuscating code (due to the implicit conversion of a function designator to pointer to the function) even like:)

```
(***JImageGetResource)(jimage, location, val, size);
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

void hello( const char *s )
{
    std::cout << "Hello " << s << '\n';
}

typedef void ( *hello_t )( const char * );

int main() 
{
    hello_t fp = NULL;
    
    fp = hello;
    
    fp( "Michael Munta" );
    ( *fp )( "Michael Munta" );
    ( ***fp )( "Michael Munta" );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello Michael Munta
Hello Michael Munta
Hello Michael Munta
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, I googled a bit to find out how `JImageGetResource_t` is actually defined. (Google is not that clever that I thought.) I got **1** reasonable hit with something looking like a git commit uncovering: `typedef jlong(*JImageGetResource_t)(JImageFile* jimage, JImageLocationRef location, char* buffer, jlong size);` (from http://hg.openjdk.java.net/harfbuzz/jdk9/hotspot/rev/0316b41ccb2f).