# Inserting a Integer Array into a Pointer Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Can someone tell me how this compiles. How can you assign an integer array element to a pointer array element?  The weird this is that the output suggests that nums[i] is an integer rather than a pointer, however nums was defined as a pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   int n;
    int *nums = NULL;
    nums = new int[n];  // Assign pointer nums to a address in heap allocated for a integer array of n-elements.
    n=5;
    int Array[n] = {5,4,3,6,8};
    
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    {
   nums [i] = Array[i];
   std::cout << nums[i] << " , " << &nums[i] << std::endl;
    }

    delete []nums;

    return 0;}
```

I get the following output:

```
5 , 0x786cd0
4 , 0x786cd4
3 , 0x786cd8
6 , 0x786cdc
8 , 0x786ce0
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: `nums` is a pointer and `nums[i]` dereferences the pointer at index i

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "dereferencing" a pointer mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean)

Answer (score 2):

> How can you assign an integer array element to a pointer array element?

`nums` is a pointer to a dynamic array of `int` elements, in this case to the 1st `int` in the array. Dereferencing `nums[i]` yields an `int&` reference to the `i`th element in the array.

`Array` is a fixed array of `int` elements. When a fixed array is accessed by its name, it *decays* into a pointer to the 1st element. So, dereferencing `Array[i]` also yields an `int&` reference to the `i`th element in the array.

Thus, `nums[i] = Array[i];` is simply assigning an `int` to an `int`. Nothing weird about that.

> the output suggests that `nums[i]` is an integer rather than a pointer

That is correct, it is.

> however `nums` was defined as a pointer

That is also correct. It is a pointer to an `int`, in this case the 1st `int` in the dynamic array.

---

Also, on a side note, your code has *undefined behavior* because `n` is uninitialized when used to allocate `nums`, and `int Array[n]` is [non-standard behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/) since `n` is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: My guess is they assumed `nums` would somehow be an array of pointers.