# derefrencing in linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm learning C and saw this segment of code for creating a linked list :

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;

void print_list(node_t * head) {
    node_t * current = head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", current->val);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

My question is , if `current` is simply a pointer holding a memory address how can the `->` operator be applied to it in `current->val` , expecting a decimal to be printed - `printf("%d\n", current->val);` ignoring the format specifier surely this , would print a memory address rather than a literal value , as it hans't been dereferenced , or is it the arrow operator that does the dereferencing?

Comment: `val` isn't a pointer, why do you think it needs to be dereferenced?

Comment: `a->b` is essentially equivalent to `(*a).b`

Comment: The latter. `current->` means what "`current` points to".

Comment: My question wasn't passive-aggressive, I have no idea how you got to that conclusion. Or do you consider asking for clarification to be aggressive?

Comment: Here and there C offers syntactic sugar for frequently applied expressions, like what Mat already indicated – another example is `a[b]` for `*(a + b)`...

Comment: long-winded, but have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean). Just do a text search for `->` to find that section

Comment: @UnholySheep you can simply state that it doesnt , answering a question with another question doesnt help anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if `current` is simply a pointer holding a memory address

It is.  Its declaration leaves no room for doubt.

> how can the `->` operator be applied to it in `current->val` ,

`->` is an operator applicable (only) to objects having pointer-to-structure types.

> expecting a decimal to be printed - `printf("%d\n", current->val)`

The result of an `->` expression is the designated member of the pointed-to structure.  The member itself, not a pointer to it.  The expression `(a)->b` is exactly equivalent to `(*(a)).b`.  So,

> or is it the arrow operator that does the dereferencing?

Yes.

Comment: In your third remark, the extra parentheses do not improve the clarity.  I suggest editing to: _The expression `a->b` is exactly equivalent to `(*a).b`_

Comment: if , say both a AND b are pointers would a -> b - equivelent to (*a).(*b)?

Comment: @Exiatron00: no, it would still be equivalent to `(*a).b`.