# If e is a pointer then why . operator is being used instead of ->?

Tags: c, pointers

Code works fine.
[Output received from some input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpJT0.png)
In several places after the term e[something] '.' operator is used. Since ***e is a pointer*** that holds address to an element, Why isn't '->' operator is used. Is it so because ***e[something] will hold an entire structure as value*** to that index=something instead of an address to the element?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct element{
  int i;
  int j;
  int x;  //x represents value of A[i][j]
};

struct sparse{
  int m;
  int n;
  int num;  // num represents no. of non-zero elements
  struct element *e;
};

void create(struct sparse *);
void display(struct sparse);

void create(struct sparse *s){
  printf("Enter Dimensions :\n");
  scanf("%d%d", &s->m, &s->n);
  printf("Enter number of non-zero elements :");
  scanf("%d", &s->num);

  s->e = (struct element *) malloc(s->num * sizeof(struct element));

  printf("Enter i, j, x :\n");
  for(int k = 0; k < s->num; k++){
    scanf("%d%d%d", &s->e[k].i, &s->e[k].j, &s->e[k].x); // why not s->e[k]->i
  }
}

void display(struct sparse s){
  int p, q, k = 0;
  for(p = 0; p < s.m; p++){
    for(q = 0; q < s.n; q++){
      if(p == s.e[k].i && q == s.e[k].j){
        printf("%d ", s.e[k].x);
        k++;
      }
      else{
        printf("0 ");
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main(){
  struct sparse s;

  create(&s);
  display(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `e` is essentially an array of elements. It's a pointer to the first element. The `[]` dereferences, so you can use the `.` Which is almost what you've described in your question. I suspect there is a dup for this.

Comment: `e` is a pointer but `e[something]` is not.

Comment: This isn't quite a dup, but the answer does cover your scenerio. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955297/2067492

Answer (score 1):

**back to basics of arrays** :

`arr[i]` is equivalent to `*(arr + i)` and `arr` itself is the base address of the array

so `e[k]` is equivalent to `*(e + k)` and `e` value itself is just address.

so when you say `*(e + k)` this means that you have the actual instance not a pointer that points to its place. as you dereference `e` using `[]` operator.

the only case that you can write  `e[k]->i;` is when `e[k]` itself is a pointer but in your case `e[k]` isn't a pointer , as said above , it's equivalent to `*(e + k)` so it's dereferenced and `*(address)` will give you the actual instance in the memory that `e + k` points to.

Answer (score 1):

```
s->e = (struct element *) malloc(s->num * sizeof(struct element));
```

`e` points to an array of structs.

doing something like `s->e[i].member` is completely legal. We can use `.` because `e[i]` isn't pointer.

So if it isn't a pointer what is it?

`e[i]` is some **value/data** at an address.  Specifically `e[i]` is some value/data at the address of the ith struct in `e`. Using `e[i]` will allow us to reference the ith struct.

When we do `e[i]` it's the same as `*(e+i)`. Notice how a `*` (dereference operator) is used. This will get us the **value/data** that we need from the address that `e+i` points to, which in turn will enable us to access its members.