# pointers in functions don't return what I want

Tags: c, pointers

I have two functions, I need one to add a value to a variable and the other to print it, but the output is incorrect to what I expect.

What I do is define a function, passing a sum pointer as a parameter, in another function I create the variable that I will pass as a parameter and I invoke the new function passing that variable as an address, but when printing it it fails.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void test() {
        int sum;
        test2(&sum);
        printf("%d",sum);
    }

    void test2(int *sumador) {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sumador += i;
        }
    }

    int main() {
        test();
    }
```

Comment: `int i` is uninitialized. It seems like you assume it starts with a value of 0, but if that's what you want you need `int i = 0;`.

Comment: What do you think `sumador+=i` does?

Comment: keeps printing wrong

Comment: sumador+=i add from 0 to 10 the sumador variable

Comment: You're changing a pointer, not what it points at.

Comment: sumador+=i add from 0 to 9 ,srry

Comment: A key thing that is uninitialized here is `int sum;`. Using it that way could produce any result. Use `int sum=0;`. In addition, as @StephenNewell correctly points out, you never change it value in test2, only the value of a local pointer that started out pointing to it.

Comment: Do you know [what does "dereferencing" a pointer mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you should dereference the pointer before summing with "i", like this:

```c
*sumador += i;
```

This happens because "sumador" is a pointer and the content of the pointer is a memory address. In your original code you are adding "i" to the address stored in "sumador", what you actually want is to sum "i" with the content contained in the memory address stored in the pointer, which is the process we called dereferencing.

Another problem is that in function `test` make sure to initialize
the value of the variable sum.

```c
int sum = 0;
```

Also, because test2 is called inside test, you should declare the function test2 above the function test, not below it, like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void test2(int *sumador) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        *sumador += i;
    }
}

void test() {
    int sum = 0;
    test2(&sum);
    printf("%d",sum);
}


int main() {
    test();
}
```

I hope I was able to help you,
have a nice day!

Comment: Well, yes actually, I forgot about that, let me make a correction in my post,

Comment: @MysteRys337: If you want the person to which you are replying to be automatically notified of your comment, you must write the person's name using the `@` syntax, as I am doing with you. Press the "Help" button when writing a comment for further information.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks @AndreasWenzel, now I know that hahaha

Comment: When writing a comment to a post, the owner of the post will automatically be notified of your comment. But other people will not be notified, unless they happen to be following the question. That is why it is important to use the `@` syntax with the person's name when replying to a comment. I do not have to write your name so that you are notified, because you are the owner of the post to which I am attaching this comment.