# value of function in c/C++

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does dereferencing of a function pointer happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795575/how-does-dereferencing-of-a-function-pointer-happen)

If we have

```
void f() {
    printf("called");
}
```

Then the following code will result in output of "calledcalled":

```
f();
(*f)();
```

I don't really understand how this works…what is the difference between `*f` and `f`? And why would you call a function using the latter syntax?

Comment: This needs to be two questions, one about C, one about C++, because they have subtly different rules (although the same behavior in the end).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to call a function in C++:

By name:

```
f();
```

Through a function pointer:

```
typedef void (*fptr_t)();
fptr_t fptr = &f;
(*fptr)();
```

Now, using the address-of operator on a function name (`&f`) obviously creates a function pointer.  But the function name can implicitly convert to a function pointer when certain conditions are met.  So the above code could be written as:

```
typedef void (*fptr_t)();
fptr_t fptr = f; // no address-of operator, implicit conversion
(*fptr)();
```

Your second example is doing exactly this, but using a temporary variable to hold the function pointer instead of a named local variable.

I prefer to use address-of when creating function pointers, the meaning is much clearer.

A related note: The function call operator will automatically dereference a function pointer if one is provided.  So this also is legal:

```
typedef void (*fptr_t)();
fptr_t fptr = &f;
fptr();
```

That's pretty useful with templates, because the same syntax works whether you have a function pointer or a functor (object implementing `operator()`) passed in.

And neither shortcut works with pointer-to-members, there you NEED explicit address-of and dereference operators.

---

In C, [@Mehrdad explains that all function calls use a function pointer.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541686/mehrdad)

Comment: I expect that we'll be seeing even more subtle issues in C++0x, with lambdas and all...

Answer (score 6):

The first one is somewhat of a syntactic sugar for the second one. The second one makes it obvious that you're making the call through a pointer, and it's used mainly with function pointers rather than regular functions, to make the distinction more obvious.

Comment: So is the second one implicitly taking the pointer to `f`, and then calling the function via that?

Comment: @Matti: No, the second one is *dereferencing* the pointer and calling the function, which is what the first one *implicitly* does. (The `*` symbol has several meanings -- it can be both the dereferencing *operator* and a pointer *declaration*, aside from multiplication. Don't get them confused.)

Comment: f is an address.  (*f)() is a function call to that address.

Comment: Actually, yes: the second one is implicitly interpreted as `(*&f)();`, but this is only due to C heritage.  In C++ you 'should' take the address of explicitly.

Comment: @Jan: I believe the *first* one is implicitly interpreted like that, not the second one... `f` *is* the function pointer, not a value whose *address* is the pointer.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I'm pretty sure a plain call to a function and a call via a function pointer are (at least without optimization) compiled differently, so by default `f` is just the function `f` and not a pointer to it. What I meant by "implicitly taking the pointer" referred to the lack of `&`.

Comment: @Matti: I'm confused -- what is the distinction between "the function `f`" and "a pointer to the function `f`"? AFAIK the function *is* the pointer and nothing else... `&f` just makes it obvious that you mean the address of `f`, but otherwise, it's just like how the name of an array is the same as the address of its first element.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Technically, `f` is a function, and `&f` is the "address" of a function; they have different types.  But typically, one degrades into another, just like for arrays turning into pointers (which are *not* the same thing, by the way...).

Comment: @Oli: I still don't see the distinction -- in what way is a function `f` different from its address `&f`? AFAIK they're the same semantically (both are l-values, both have the same data type, etc.)

Comment: Guys, `f` and `*f` are the same thing because the indirection operator, when applied to a function, returns a function designator which is the same as the function itself. This is discussed at length [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795575/how-does-dereferencing-of-a-function-pointer-happen).

Comment: @Frederic: Nice catch, voting to close as duplicate...

Comment: @Mehrdad: A plain call to a function and a call via a pointer to it get compiled into different kinds of instructions on a lot of platforms. That's what makes a function and a pointer to it different. In the trivial case of something like `(*&f)()` the whole pointer thing gets optimized away and becomes a plain call in the end, though.

Comment: @Matti: I wasn't asking how the *call* is different, I was saying how the *value* of `f` and `&f` are not different. Yes, there's an indirect call and there's a direct call, but that's only because of a compiler optimization, not a C semantics difference.

Comment: @Mehrdad: But the semantics ARE different.  There is no function pointer involved in the line `f();`.

Comment: @Ben: `f` *is* the (r-value) pointer... I don't see how that's any different.

Comment: I couldn't just let this go and I went and took a look at [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (section 6.5.2.2) (or at least the first of many C standards I could find) - and indeed, function calls are defined as a postfix operator where the function to call is an expression that returns a function pointer. There's even a footnote that mentions that "Most often, this is the result of converting an identifier that is a function designator." So, all function calls are defined via pointers. Guess you learn something new every day...

Comment: @Mehrdad, @Matti: Latest C++ standard language: "For an ordinary function call,  the postfix
expression shall be either an lvalue that refers to a function (in which case the function-to-pointer standard
conversion (4.3) is suppressed on the postfix expression), or it shall have pointer to function type."  Just another reason that the only questions that should be tagged both `c` and `c++` are the ones "How can I make this work in both C and C++" or related "Explain this difference between C and C++".

Comment: @Matti: That's what I always thought. :) @Ben: Interesting, so it's different in C++? Did *not* know that...

Answer (score 2):

Just as an array type is almost entirely equivalent to the corresponding pointer-to-element type, a function type is entirely equivalent to the corresponding pointer-to-function type:

```
void (*func1)() = f;  // function type -> pointer-to-function type
void (*func2)() = &f; // pointer-to-function type -> pointer-to-function type
```

and also

```
void (*func)() = ...;
func();               // pointer-to-function type + function-call operator
(*func)();            // function type + function-call operator
```

So, in

```
(*f)();
```

you're dereferencing `f` (implicitly converted to `&f`), and then apply the function-call operator.