# Why doesn't * and & have no effect on functions?

Tags: c, function

Code:

```
#include <pthread.h>

void *thread(void* o) {
    return NULL;
}

void man(void)
{
    pthread_create(NULL, NULL, &***thread, NULL);
}
```

It compiles without warnings with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`. You can add more asterisks before thread, they don't have any effect. What was the reasoning between that? Why doesn't it give an error instead of being silent? Was this specified by C11?

Comment: `void man(void)`?

Comment: @SeanBright I think the edit might have broken the question. `void main` should probably give warnings.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I reverted that part of the edit. Apologies.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518815/function-pointer-automatic-dereferencing

Comment: Assuming `int main(void)` I get two warnings: `unused parameter 'o'` and `null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument` (the first argument to `pthread_create()`). Not sure how you compiled with no warnings.

Comment: Short answer: backwards compatibility. Pre-C89/C90, a function pointer `foo` needed to be dereferenced before it could be called, e.g. `(*foo)(param1, param2);`, and it was necessary to take the address of a function to convert it to a pointer, e.g. `foo = &somefunction;`. In C89/C90 that was changed to make it easier for programmers who could now call a function pointer `foo` like `foo(param1, param2);` and could assign a function to a function pointer without using the address-of operator, e.g. `foo = somefunction;`. For backwards compatibility, `&` and `*` need to have no effect.

Comment: ... cont. However, applying multiple consecutive `&` to a function is not allowed. E.g. `foo = &&somefunction;` is not allowed, but `foo = &*&somefunction;` is allowed, as is `foo = *&****&*somefunction;`.

Comment: ...cont. So indeed `&` has _some_ effect as it produces an _rvalue_ and you cannot take the address of an _rvalue_.