# Can I dereference the address of an integer pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to figure out all the possible ways I could fill in int pointer k considering the following givens:

```
int i = 40;    
int *p = &i;    
int *k = ___;
```

So far I came up with "&i" and "p". However, is it possible to fill in the blank with "*&p" or "&*p"?

My understanding of "*&p" is that it is dereferencing the address of an integer pointer. Which to me means if printed out would output the content of p, which is &i. Or is that not possible when initializing an int pointer? Or is it even possible at all anytime?

I understand "&*p" as the memory address of the integer *p points to. This one I am really unsure about also.

If anyone has any recommendations or suggestions I will greatly appreciate it! Really trying to understand pointers better.

Comment: "is it possible to fill in the blank with ..." - what does the compiler say?

Comment: `int *k = p; printf ("*k is: %d\n", *k);`

Comment: `k = &*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&i;`

Answer (score 2):

**Pointer Basics**

A pointer is simply a normal variable that holds the *address of* something else as its value. In other words, a pointer *points to* the address where something else can be found. Where you normally think of a variable holding an immediate values, such as `int i = 40;`, a pointer (e.g. `int *p = &i;`) would simply hold the address where `40` is stored in memory.

If you need the value stored at the memory address `p` points to, you *dereference* `p` using the unary `'*'` operator, e.g. `int j = *p;` will initialize `j = 40`).

Since `p` points to the address where `40` is stored, if you change that value at that address (e.g. `*p = 41;`) `41` is now stored at the address where `40` was before. Since `p` points to the address of `i` and you have changed the value at that address, `i` now equals `41`. However `j` resides in another memory location and its value was set before you changed the value at the address for `i`, the value for `j` remains `40`.

If you want to create a second pointer (e.g. `int *k;`) you are just creating another variable that holds an address as its value. If you want `k` to reference the same address held by `p` as its value, you simply initialize `k` the same way you woul intialize any other varaible by assigning its value when it is declared, e.g. `int *k = p;` (which is the same as assigning `k = p;` at some point after initialization).

**Pointer Arithmetic**

Pointer arithmetic works the same way regardless of the type of object pointed to because the `type` of the pointer controls the pointer arithmetic, e.g. with a `char *` pointer, `pointer+1` points to the next byte (next `char`), for an `int *` pointer (normal 4-byte integer), `pointer+1` will point to the next `int` at an offset 4-bytes after `pointer`. (so a pointer, is just a pointer.... where arithmetic is automatically handled by the `type`)

**Chaining & and * Together**

The operators available to take the address of an object and dereference pointers are the unary `'&'` (*address of*) operator and the unary `'*'` (*dereference*) operator. `'&'` in taking the address of an object ***adds one level of indirection***. `'*'` in dereferening a pointer to get the value (or thing) pointed to by the pointer ***removes one level of indirection***. So as @KamilCuk explained in example in his comment it does not matter how many times you apply one after the other, one simply ***adds*** and the other ***removes*** a level of indirection making all but the final operator superfluous.

(**note:** when dealing with an *array-of-pointers*, the postfix `[..]` operator used to obtain the pointer at an index of the array also acts to *derefernce* the array of pointers removing one level of indirection)

**Your Options**

Given your declarations:

```
int i = 40;    
int *p = &i;    
int *k = ___;
```

and the pointer summary above, you have two options, both are equivalent. You can either initialize the pointer `k` with the address of `i` directly, e.g.

```
int *k = &i;
```

or you can initialize `k` by assinging the address held by `p`, e.g.

```
int *k = p;
```

Either way, `k` now holds, as its value, the memory location for `i` where `40` is currently stored.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little bit unsure what you're trying to do but,

```
int* p = &i;
```

now, saying `&*p` is really just like saying `p` since this gives you the address.

Just that  `p` is much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is (quoting [C11 standard footnote 102](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note102)) that for any pointer `E`

```
&*E is equivalent to E
```

You can have as many `&*&*&*...` in front of any pointer type variable that is on the right side of `=`.

With the `&*&*&*` sequence below I denote: zero or more `&*` sequences. I've put a space after it so it's, like, somehow visible. So: we can assign pointer `k` to the address of `i`:

```
int *k = &*&*&* &i;
```

and assign `k` to the same value as `p` has:

```
int *k = &*&*&* p;
```

We can also take the address of pointer p, so do `&p`, it will have `int**` - ie. it will be a pointer to a pointer to `int`. And then we can dereference that address. So `*&p`. It will be always equal to `p`.

```
int *k = &*&*&* *&p;
```

> is it possible to fill in the blank with "*&p" or "&*p"?

Yes, both are correct. The `*&p` first takes the address of `p` variables then deferences it, as I said above. The `*&variable` should be always equal to the value of `variable`. The second `&*p` is equal to `p`.

> My understanding of "*&p" is that it is dereferencing the address of an integer pointer. Which to me means if printed out would output the content of p, which is &i. Or is that not possible when initializing an int pointer? Or is it even possible at all anytime?

Yes and yes. It is possible, anytime, with any type. The `&*` is possible with complete types only.

Side note: It's get really funny with functions. The dereference operator `*` is ignored in front of a function or a function pointer. This is just a rule in C. See ex. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518815/function-pointer-automatic-dereferencing). You can have a infinite sequence of `*` and `&` in front of a function or a function pointer as long as there are no `&&` sequences in it. It gets ridiculous:

```
void func(void);
void (*funcptr)(void) = ***&***********&*&*&*&****func;
void (*funcptr2)(void) = ***&***&***&***&***&*******&******&**funcptr;
```

Both `funcptr` and `funcptr2` are assigned the same value and both point to function `func`.

Comment: You can also do things like `&0[&i]` i.e. `&(&i)[0]`

Comment: Anyone reasonably sane won't abuse those rules even for [The International Obfuscated C Code Contest](https://www.ioccc.org/) nowadays.

Comment: "*for any variable E

`&*E is equivalent to E`*" not really. This only holds for pointers. Same here: "*It is possible, anytime, with any type. The &* is possible with complete types only.*". The other way round it indeed hold for any variable: `*&E == E`

Comment: Gosh. I had "for any pointer E". Then edited to "for any variable E" for no reason.