# C++ Pointer (Array)

Tags: c++, pointers

Here is the code of my tutorial

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[5] = {8,2,9,4,5},a,b,*ptr;
    int c = 5;

    ptr = arr;
    a = *ptr + 10;
    ptr = &c;   
    ptr += 2;
    cout<<*(ptr+1);
}
```

I'm a little confused why the output is 9. When `ptr` is pointing to `c`, which is valued 5, how can the pointer be incremented +2 since `c` is not an array?

Comment: Yikes! There is only one `c`. When you set `ptr = &c;`, the `ptr` points to (holds the address of) `c`. Doing `ptr += 2;` puts you 2 integers (8-bytes) after `c`. (that is *undefined behavior* -- that's not part of `c` -- no pun intended, well maybe...)

Comment: Where did you get this code from?

Comment: Here is a pointer basics post that may help [Can I dereference the address of an integer pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57451436/can-i-dereference-the-address-of-an-integer-pointer/57451658?r=SearchResults&s=2|42.6216#57451658)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Undefined behavior**

Let's break it down:

```
int arr[5] = {8,2,9,4,5},a,b,*ptr;
int c = 5;

ptr = arr;      // ptr = address of arr[0]
a = *ptr + 10;  // a = (arr[0] + 10) = (8 + 10) = 18
ptr = &c;       // ptr = address of c
ptr += 2;       // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR, c is not an array
cout<<*(ptr+1); // COULD PRINT ANYTHING
```

Not that we've established undefined behavior, the language lawyers can't sue me to explain what might be happening:

The variables of `main` are *possibly* piled onto the stack as follows.  It's convenient that the elements on the stack are integer for this simple example:

```
0x100 c 
0x104 arr[0]
0x108 arr[1]
0x10C arr[2]
0x110 arr[3]
0x114 arr[4]
0x118 a
0x11C b
0x120 ptr // address of the variable ptr, not what ptr points to
```

Hence, `ptr+2` is the same address as the arr[1] in the array, which holds a value of "2".  And then then the additional `(ptr+1)` expression is the address of arr[2], which holds the value 9.

But that's because you are getting lucky.  Any other system or compiler could crash the program or make the lights dim in your house.  Such is the nature of undefined behavior.

Comment: `ptr += 2` is not undefined behavior. It's only undefined once you dereference.

Comment: Language lawyers.  I can never escape them.

Comment: It's the only taste of control I have in this chaotic world :(

Comment: @John I believe the behavior of `ptr += 2` is undefined, though `ptr += 1` would be OK. See 8.7 [expr.add] paragraph 4. The "(possibly-hypothetical) element" wording refers only to a single element past the end of the array. (`c` is treated as a 1-element array.)

Comment: @Keith that's such a hairy sentence. I think you're right. Footnote 86) in that was key to me being able to parse it.

Comment: A quibble: "*UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR, c is not an array*" - No, `c` is not an array, but `c` is treated as a 1-element array for purposes of pointer arithmetic. The problem is that the array object that `c` is equivalent to is not big enough. `p+1` is a valid one-past-the-end pointer (dereferencing it would have UB), but `p+2` by itself has UB.

Comment: @KeithThompson incrementing a pointer beyond the 1-past-end is not UB, as long as the pointer is not dereferenced. That same pointer is allowed to be decremented to bring it back into valid range. That would not be possible if the increment were UB to  begin with.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, it is UB, and no, that's not possible. C++17 8.7 [expr.add] paragraph 4:"When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type
of the pointer operand. If the expression `P` points to element `x[i]` of an array object `x` with `n` elements, 
the expressions `P + J` and `J + P` (where `J` has the value `j`) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) element
`x[i + j]` `if 0 ≤ i + j ≤ n;` otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the * in ptr

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int arr[5] = {8,2,9,4,5},a,b,*ptr;
    int c = 5;

    ptr = arr;
    a = *ptr + 10;
    ptr = &c;
    (*ptr) += 2;
    cout<<*(ptr+1);
}
```

It will print 8, But your program undefined behavior due to this line

```
  ptr += 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the pointer is `not` pointing to `c`.

when you did `ptr += 2;` the pointer got incremented from `c` and is now pointing to a memory space having a garbage value.

When I ran the code I got `612602545` as output which clearly is a garbage value. The output you get will differ each time you run the code or from system to system.

Answer (score 0):

Output of your program is not deterministic. ptr pointing to c has been incremented by 2. As ptr was not pointing to contiguous memory structure (Like array), it is not possible to determine what ptr is pointing at after increment. As it is int pointer, every increment will cause it to jump by sizeof(int). Derefrencing ptr after increment will try to read next sizeof(int) bytes as int. So you can get any garbage value.