# dereferencing function pointer to function returning void throws error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

Tags: c, function-pointers, void, dereference, function-call

I am a beginner in C language. Read various SO threads on function pointers. For instance, [How does dereferencing of a function pointer happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795575/how-does-dereferencing-of-a-function-pointer-happen), [Function Pointer - Automatic Dereferencing [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518815/function-pointer-automatic-dereferencing?noredirect=1&lq=1), so I tried to do an experiment of mine.

Couldn't understand why this error is thrown since I am not using the void value anywhere..

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f(int j) {
    static int i;
    if (j == 1)
        printf("f: i entered this function main()\n");
    else if(j == 2)
        printf("f: i entered this function through pointer to function\n");
    
    void (*recurse)(int);
    recurse = *f; // "f" is a reference; implicitly convert to ptr.
    if (i == 0){
        i++;
        *recurse(2); 
    } else
        return;
}

int main(void)  
{
    f(1);
    return 0;
}
```

GCC Version is 11.2.0
Compiler flags used include -std=c99
if I modify line 14 to `recurse(2)` then the program runs smoothly. No error or warning is thrown by the compiler.

```
$ gcc testing11.c @compilerflags11.2.0.txt -o testing11.exe
testing11.c: In function ‘f’:
testing11.c:14:10: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
   14 |         *recurse(2);
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Just do `recurse(2);`. Though may I add that 1) doing recursion is a very bad idea in general and 2) doing recursion through a function pointer is an incredibly bad idea. This function might not have been possible to tail call optimize in the first place, but by making the call through a function pointer you have almost certainly blocked all optimization. For what purpose?

Comment: @Lundin As I wrote, `recurse(2)` is working. Thank you for pointing out the recursive function implemented through function pinter being a bottleneck for optimization. Would learn more about the same. (At the moment, I understand little about compilation process and optimization)

Comment: There barely exists any scenario in the real world when recursion should be used in C. So if you don't understand how machine code is generated from C source, then I strongly advise against using recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression statement

```
*recurse(2);
```

is equivalent to

```
*( recurse(2) );
```

So as the return type of the function is `void` then you are trying to dereference the type `void`.

It seems you mean

```
( *recurse )(2);
```

Or you could just write

```
recurse(2);
```

because the expression `*recurse` used in the first call will be again implicitly converted to a function pointer.

So though this call for example

```
( ******recurse )(2);
```

is correct nevertheless dereferencing the pointer expressions are redundant.