# Is there no difference between a function address and the function address' address?

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers, memory-address

```
void f()
{}

void test()
{
    auto fn_1 = f;
    auto fn_2 = &f;

    assert(fn_1 == fn_2); // OK

    fn_1();      // OK
    fn_2();      // OK
    (*fn_1)();   // OK
    (*fn_2)();   // OK
    (**fn_1)();  // OK
    (**fn_2)();  // OK
    (***fn_1)(); // OK
    (***fn_2)(); // OK
}
```

Are these behaviors explicitly defined by the C++ standard?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2795803/1229023).

Comment: [Function calls](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/c3.html#3-3-2-2).

Answer (score 1):

Yes the ampersand is optional, they  produce the same result.

> An lvalue of function type T can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T.” The result is a pointer to the function.55

I'm just gonna go ahead and say if your using c++11 you should be using `std::function` anyway it's much easier to understand and use.

Comment: Could you refer me to the Holy standard?

Answer (score 1):

The issue at play here is that a function decays into a function pointer.  The types of both of the variables `fn_1` and `fn_2` are `void (*)()`, i.e. "pointer to function taking no arguments and returning `void`".  In the case of `fn_1`, the function `f` decays into a pointer to a function, while in the case of `fn_2`, you explicitly assign a pointer to a function to `fn_2`, and no decaying takes place.