# Function pointer vs Function reference

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference, function-pointers

In the code below, function-pointer and what i considered as "function-reference" seems to have identical semantics:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

void func(int a) {
    cout << "Hello" << a << '\n';
}
void func2(int a) {
    cout << "Hi" << a << '\n';
}

int main() {
    void (& f_ref)(int) = func;
    void (* f_ptr)(int) = func;

    // what i expected to be, and is, correct:
    f_ref(1);
    (*f_ptr)(2);

    // what i expected to be, and is not, wrong:
    (*f_ref)(4); // i even added more stars here like (****f_ref)(4)
    f_ptr(3);    // everything just works!

    // all 4 statements above works just fine

    // the only difference i found, as one would expect:
//  f_ref = func2; // ERROR: read-only reference
    f_ptr = func2; // works fine!
    f_ptr(5);

    return 0;
}
```

I used gcc version 4.7.2 in Fedora/Linux

**UPDATE**

My questions are:

1. <s>Why function pointer does not require dereferencing?</s>
2. <s>Why dereferencing a function reference doesn't result in an error?</s>
3. Is(Are) there any situation(s) where I must use one over the other?
4. Why `f_ptr = &func;` works? Since func should be decayed into a pointer?
   While `f_ptr = &&func;` doesn't work (implicit conversion from `void *`)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Functions and function references (i.e. *id-expressions* of those types) decay into function pointers almost immediately, so the expressions `func` and `f_ref` actually become function pointers in your case. You can also call `(***func)(5)` and `(******f_ref)(6)` if you like.

It may be preferable to use function references in cases where you want the `&`-operator to work as though it had been applied to the function itself, e.g. `&func` is the same as `&f_ref`, but `&f_ptr` is something else.

Comment: is that an implementation bug? 'coz that goes against our intuitive concepts of "typing", right? I have also seen something like `void (*&f)(void)` as a parameter to function - `*` and `&` used together.. how come?

Comment: It's not a bug, just the way the language is defined. In expressions there are basically no functions, there are only ever function pointers; decay takes care of making the "obvious" syntax work (i.e. you can type `f(1)` rather than the more cumbersome `(&f)(1)`).

Comment: @John: Compare to the way arrays are handled; they _can't_ be passed by value, so in a function prototype, `int x[]` (and for that matter (`int x[10]`) is equivalent to `int *x`; since receiving a C array by value isn't legal, they let array declaration syntax be used as syntactic sugar for receiving a pointer.

Comment: @KerrekSB Does &f_ptr return the address of the pointer to the function?

Answer (score 16):

*"Why function pointer does not require dereferencing?"*

Because the function identifier itself is actually a pointer to the function already:

> ***4.3 Function-to-pointer conversion***
>   *§1 An lvalue of function type `T` can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to `T`.” The result is a pointer to the function.*

*"Why dereferencing a function reference doesn't result in an error?"*

Basically you can look at defining a reference as defining an alias (alternative name). Even in the standard in *8.3.2 References* in part addressing creating a reference to an object, you will find:
*"a reference can be thought of as a name of an object."*

So when you define a reference:

```
void (& f_ref)(int) = func;
```

it gives you the ability to use `f_ref` almost everywhere where it would be possible to use `func`, which is the reason why:

```
f_ref(1);
(*f_ref)(4);
```

works exactly the same way as using the `func` directly:

```
func(1);
(*func)(4);
```

Answer (score 4):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795575/how-does-dereferencing-of-a-function-pointer-happen).

The address-of operator acts like you would expect, as it points to a function but cannot be assigned. Functions are converted to function pointers when used as rvalues, which means you can dereference a function pointer any number of times and get the same function pointer back.

Answer (score 2):

As there are good answers from other people here, there is no answer explaining why `f_ptr = &&func;` does not work. When you apply the addressof operator `&` to a variable/function, you get its address. The adress itself is an r-value/a temporary variable. You cannot take the address of a temporary.

But it seems that there is a type error. The message `implicit conversion from void*` is very compiler specific for this code. I guess you are using GCC/Clang. GCC/Clang offers the ability to take the address of labels like `&&label`. The resulting value is of type `void*`. Other compilers will output something like `cannot take address of temporary` or `invalid syntax`. When using these compilers this kind of error could have been hidden without any warning in special circumstances:

```
int main() {
    int foo = 42;
    foo:;
    void* a = &foo; // take the address of a variable/function
    void* b = &&foo; // take the address of a label

    std::cout << *(int*)a << '\n';
    goto *b;
};
```

*But who would name everything the same?*