# Checking function signature using C++11 is_same?

Tags: c++, c++11, signature, type-traits

```
//test.cpp
#include <type_traits>

double* func() {}

static_assert(std::is_same<double*(*)(), decltype(func)>::value, "");

int main() {}
```

Compile command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -c test.cpp
```

Output:

```
test4.cpp:6:1: error: static assertion failed:
static_assert(std::is_same<double*(*)(), decltype(func)>::value, "");
^
```

What's wrong with the code above? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

func is a function and you check if it's a pointer to function, it's fail

See :

```
//test.cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

double d {};
double* func() { return &d ; }
auto ptr = func;

static_assert(std::is_same<double*(), decltype(func)>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_same<double*(*)(), decltype(ptr)>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_same<double*(*)(), decltype(&func)>::value, "");

double* call_func(double*(f)() )
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    return f();
}

int main() {
    call_func(func); // double* call_func(double* (*)())
}
```

I am not an expert in function pointer, what I understand :

```
double* func() { return &d ; } // is a function 
auto ptr = func; // ptr is a pointer to a function
```

May be you can see it like

```
1; // is a int
int i = 1; // i is a Lvalue expression
```

This thread may be usefull : [Function pointer vs Function reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200513/function-pointer-vs-function-reference)

And a more official link : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions  (thank to [super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55758250/checking-function-signature-using-c11-is-same/55758317?noredirect=1#comment98192873_55758317))

Comment: also `decltype(&func)` for the second `static_assert()`

Comment: @embedc It's due to implicit convertion. See [Pointer to function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) section for more details.