# Correct syntax to store function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers, implicit-conversion

Surprisingly, the following code compiles well both in gcc and clang no matter what symbol before function name is used: `*`, `&` or nothing. Does standard allow any of them? What is preferred way to store function pointers?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int foo(int a);

template <typename X>
int g(int y) {
    return y * sizeof(X);
}

int main() {

    foo* xxx;

    // 1. what is correct according to standard?
    // 2. why they all work?
    xxx = *g<float>;
    xxx = &g<float>;
    xxx = g<float>;

    printf("ok %d\n", xxx(5));
}
```

Comment: function decays to pointer.

Comment: Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200513/function-pointer-vs-function-reference).

Comment: Worth mentioning that for a pointer-to-member-function, only the syntax `&ClassName::functionname` will work.

Comment: Guess what: `xxx = &&&&g<float>` also works. And when you call through that pointer you can write `(*xxx)(5)` or `(**xxx)(5)` or even `(******xxx)(5)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All should work fine and have the same effect here. Which one is preferred is a style-issue, IMO the 1st one in your code is confusing, the other two are quite common usages.

I'll explain in the reverse order of your code for convenience,

1. For `xxx = g<float>;`, [function-to-pointer implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Function_to_pointer) is performed from `g<float>`, the converted pointer is assigned to `xxx`.
2. For `xxx = &g<float>;`, [`operator&`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator) is used explicitly to take the address of the function, the returned pointer is assigned to `xxx`.
3. For `xxx = *g<float>;`, function-to-pointer implicit conversion is performed from `g<float>`, then the pointer is dereferenced by [`operator*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_indirection_operator), which returns a function reference, on which function-to-pointer implicit conversion is performed (again), the converted pointer is assigned to `xxx` at last.