# how do the following function pointer multiple dereferences compile?

Tags: c++, compilation, function-pointers, dereference

I know with function pointers, you can call the function equivalently either using

```
 (*fptr)();
 //or 
 fptr();
```

But how do compilers achieve this? Do they completely disregard the reference token, or is there something more involved here?

Consider this valid c++ code:

```
void f1() { std::cout << "hi\n"; }
int main() {
    auto f = f1;
    (********************f1)();
    (*(*(*f1)))();
    ***************f1;
}
```

Are all the deference operators simply ignored?

And why is it not symmetrical with taking the address of functions? Here  you may refer to a function with `&` or without, but you cannot use multiple `&` signs.

For example:

```
auto pf1 = f1; // ok
auto pf2 = &f1; // ok 
//  auto pf3 = &(&(f1)); // does not compile
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function pointer vs Function reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200513/function-pointer-vs-function-reference).

Comment: Think about unary + operator on int: `+ + + + + + +42`. we just apply the operator (which indeed decays to pointer for function reference).