# derefferencing a function pointer with and without parentheses

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

What is the difference in dereferencing a function pointer with and without parentheses.
both the mechanism are working same on linux Gnu Gcc.

```
void (*fp)(void); //function pointer

void func(void);

fp = func; 

(*fp)();  //dereferencing with parentheses

fp(); // without parentheses
```

Comment: Doppelgänger : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/why-do-all-these-crazy-function-pointer-definitions-all-work-what-is-really-goi

Answer (score 1):

You need to know that

```
(*fp)() = fp()
```

The function pointer can be called in both the ways and both are valid and same.

Check the below link:

[How does dereferencing of a function pointer happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795575/how-does-dereferencing-of-a-function-pointer-happen)