# C callbacks through the function pointer and without it. Why there is no difference?

Tags: c, pointers, callback, language-lawyer

I cannot understand why different code works as it will be identical.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void foo() {
    printf("Hello\n");
}

void foo1(void fn()) {
    (*fn)();
    fn();
}

void foo2(void (*fn)()) {
    (*fn)();
    fn();
}

int main(void) {
    foo1(foo);
    foo2(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

If they identical then why this does not work?

```c
typedef void F1(), (*F2)();

int main(void) {
    F1 f1;
    F2 f2;
    // error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
    f1 = foo1;
    f2 = foo2;
    return 0;
}
```

P.S.

My interest are not in the `typedef` (second example).
I have questions only about the first example.
That is:

- Function declartions
- Function invocations

Comment: (*fn)(), (*****fn)() etc are same, as fn is a  function designator .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795575/how-does-dereferencing-of-a-function-pointer-happen

Comment: For the Reference  see 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators in C11 draft version N1570

Answer (score 1):

You are using the typedef incorrectly. The first `F1()` is not a function pointer at all. Your second part does correctly provide a typedef for a function pointer `(*F2)()`, but you fail to include a type. Bottom line, but you don't get 2 function pointer typedefs in one line:

```
typedef void (*F1)();
typedef void (*F2)();
```

Will create both a typedef for `F1` and a typedef for `F2`.

As far as the **use** of the function pointers, the function pointers may be used with, or without, parens and the dereference.

```
(*fn)();
fn();
```

Both are equivalent and simply call the function pointed to by `fn`.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look.

Comment: I need a reference to documenation as the answer.

Comment: I'll find a reference, it will take a few minutes.

Comment: @mezoni I looked through the **C11** standard and could not find a direct statement addressing the situation. There is no ambiguity in the two forms of the call, because it is clear that both refer to an address holding a function call. A secondary reference explains the use here [**Programs as Data: Function Pointers**](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html)

Answer (score 1):

The lines

```
typedef void F1();
F1 f1;
```

do not declare `f1` as a pointer. They declare `f1` as a function returning `void`. The equivalent declaration is

```
void f1();
```

This can be demonstrated by the following code, which will compile without any errors or warnings. Note that if you comment out the line `F1 f1;`, then the compiler will complain about *"implicit declaration of function f1"* and *"conflicting types for f1"* because you have a forward reference without a declaration.

```
typedef void F1();

int main(void)
{
    F1 f1;
    f1();
    return 0;
}

void f1()
{
    printf( "hello\n" );
}
```

On the other hand, the following code will also compile without warning or error, but in this case the compiler treats `f1` like a pointer to a function.

```
typedef void F1();

void foo() {
    printf( "hello\n" );
}

void foo1(F1 f1) {
    f1();
}

int main(void) {
    foo1( foo );
    return 0;
}
```

Why the difference? Because §6.7.6.3 Function declarators, paragraph 8 reads

> A declaration of a parameter as "function returning type" shall be
>   adjusted to "pointer to function returning type", as in 6.3.2.1.